# Why does integer division yield a float instead of another integer?

Tags: python, integer, python-3.x, division

Consider this division in Python 3:

```
>>> 2/2
1.0
```

Is this intended? I strongly remember earlier versions returning `int/int = int`. What should I do? Is there a new division operator or must I always cast?

---

<sub>In 2.x, the behaviour was indeed reversed; see [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869) for the opposite, 2.x-specific problem.</sub>

Comment: Yes, that's the way division works in 3.x.

Comment: Here's a post by Python's creator talking about how the rounding works, it's orthogonal to your question but I found it interesting: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Comment: @hughdbrown so that means for **all** python 3 version essentially?

Comment: @hughdbrown: yes, [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) is *final*, meaning both accepted and implemented.

Comment: If you are doing anything other than simple division, then casting the float result is a better method.  For example, calculating 480 // 640 * 320 results in 0

Comment: @brianlmerritt depends on what you're doing and *why*. Working in integer arithmetic is more straightforward, and problems with precision can typically be addressed by just making sure that multiplications happen before divisions: `480 * 320 // 640` wives the expected `240`.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Take a look at [PEP-238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/): Changing the Division Operator

> The // operator will be available to request floor division unambiguously.

Comment: @JonathanSternberg except for all the code that was written for python 2.0.  I feel like the role of / and // should be reversed to keep backwards compatibility.  Also, in pretty much every other language / preserves type.  i would make more sense then for // to automatically convert to float, not /.

Comment: The second part (after the "Also") makes sense (similarity to other languages) but regarding the first part, the whole _point_ of Python 3 was to NOT be backwards compatible with Python 2, but rather fix up a bunch of problems with Python 2. Enough people found the ambiguity of `/` to be enough of a language design "mistake" that needed to be fixed in Python 3. It may have been a controversial decision, but enough people felt it was the correct one. Count me in the group that loves the change. It is nice we can all agree to disagree. Cheers. :)

Comment: I understand the reason why Python does it in the instances of the answer not being #.0, but not for instances where the answer is #.0. Float 1.0 is the same as integer 1, so when the numbers being calculated are integers that result in a float that's the equivalent of an integer, why not just return or print an integer? That at least keeps the types consistent and intuitive. If an answer would include a non-zero decimal number, then the float should be returned. Other languages I've used work this way (smartly), none of them return #.0 when the answer is an integer.

Answer (score 77):

Oops, immediately found `2//2`. This will output an int rather than a float.

Comment: This seems to not work for negative numbers. -1//5 return -1 and -5//5 returns -1.

Comment: @mschuett: this is to be expected, and is the same result as with Python 2.

Comment: Yeah I did some more digging and found that out as well. However I would imagine a decent size number of people do not realize this depending on the language they come from.

Comment: @TylerH I doubt there was any confusion in the past 12 years that warranted your edit?

Comment: @JonasByström The upvoted comments asking for clarification and giving that clarification weren't a clue? Hard to see how one *wouldn't* see an obvious opportunity for improvement from the original version of the answer. Good answers provide the solution *and* an explanation of said solution. Readers might otherwise use `//` instead of `/` because of this answer and cause code that depends on a float to break, not realizing the implications.

Comment: `//` only yields an int if the two divisors are ints.

Comment: @eatingthenight please see [What is the reason for difference between integer division and float to int conversion in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304235).

Answer (score 61):

### Behavior of the division operator in Python 2.7 and Python 3

In Python 2.7: By default, division operator will return integer output.

To get the result in double, multiply the dividend or divisor by 1.0.

```
100/35 => 2 # Expected is 2.857142857142857
(100*1.0)/35 => 2.857142857142857
100/(35*1.0) => 2.857142857142857
```

In Python 3

```
// => used for integer output
/ => used for double output

100/35 => 2.857142857142857
100//35 => 2
100.//35 => 2.0    # Floating-point result if the divisor or dividend is real
```

Comment: By the way, no need to multiply by 1.0. It is enough that one of the numbers is a float. E.g., 100/35.0 = 100.0/35 = 2.857142857142857

Comment: `//` is not "used for integer output". `//` is the result of the `floor()` function to the result of the division, which in turns yields an integer if the two operands are integers and a float if at least one of them is a float, for types coherence.

Answer (score 25):

The accepted answer already mentions [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/). I just want to add a quick look behind the scenes for those interested in what's going on without reading the whole PEP.

Python maps operators like `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` to special functions, such that e.g. `a + b` is equivalent to

```
a.__add__(b)
```

Regarding division in Python 2, there is by default only `/` which maps to `__div__` and the result is dependent on the input types (e.g. `int`, `float`).

Python 2.2 introduced the `__future__` feature `division`, which changed the division semantics the following way (TL;DR of PEP 238):

- `/` maps to `__truediv__` which must "return a reasonable approximation of
  the mathematical result of the division" (quote from PEP 238)
- `//` maps to `__floordiv__`, which should return the floored result of `/`

With Python 3.0, the changes of PEP 238 became the default behaviour and there is no more special method `__div__` in Python's object model.

If you want to use the same code in Python 2 and Python 3 use

```
from __future__ import division
```

and stick to the PEP 238 semantics of `/` and `//`.