# What does //= in python do?

Tags: python

I'm reading http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex37.html but I don't understand what the `//=` symbol does.  `/=` makes sense to me:

```
a = 9
a /= 3
a == 3 # => True
```

But `//=`

```
a = 9
a //= 3
a == 3 # => Also True
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//` works as an "integer divide" in python3, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1282945/118150).

In C, division with `/` on integers works as a "division with floor" or "integer divide". In order to provide this capability, python provides the `//` operator, unlike `/` which will give a floating point result.

The authoritative reference is certainly [pep-238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

From the command-line version (useful when you're trying to figure out things like this):

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, ...
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 10
>>> a/3
3.3333333333333335
>>> a//3
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

`/` as you know does *classic division*. `//` operator was added in Python 2.2 which does *floor division*, and with addition of this operator, you can use `from __future__ import division` to make `/` operator do `true` division.

`a  //= 3` is equivalent to `a = a // 3`.

So, here's the summary:

```
Python Version       operator /       operator //
-------------------------------------------------
2.1x and older        classic           Not Added

2.2 and newer         classic           floor
(without import)      

2.2 and newer          true             floor
(with import)
```

Comment: To nitpick, it's equivalent to `a = a.__ifloordiv__(3)` if that method is defined (cf. http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ifloordiv__). I *think* some types (perhaps NumPy arrays?) override that operator to act in-place. Still, it rarely matters.

Comment: @delnan -- For types which are mutable, the api expects that it acts in place although it doesn't actually have to.

Answer (score 0):

`//` is floor division: it divides and rounds down, though it still produces a float if the operands are floats.  In Python 2, it's the same as regular division for integers, unless you use `from __future__ import division` to get Python 3's "true" division behavior.

So, yes, this is a little complicated.  Essentially it exists to recreate the behavior you get in Python 2 by dividing two integers, because that changes in Python 3.

In Python 2:

- `11 / 5` → `2`
- `11.0 / 5.0` → `2.2`
- `11 // 5` → `2`
- `11.0 // 5.0` → `2.0`

In Python 3, **or** Python 2 with `from __future__ import division`, **or** Python 2 run with `-Q new`:

- `11 / 5` → `2.2`
- `11.0 / 5.0` → `2.2`
- `11 // 5` → `2`
- `11.0 // 5.0` → `2.0`

And, of course, adding the `=` just turns it into a combo assignment operator like `/=`.