# Function in Python keeps returning unnecessary floats

Tags: python, function, variables, type-conversion

I have the following code, which keeps producing errors:

```
import math
def pen_checker(number):
    print(number)
    for x in range(1, number):
        y = x*(3*x-1)/2
        if(number == y):
            return True
    return False
def pen_calculator(n):
    x = n*(3*n-1)/2
    return x
def main():
    pen1 = 1
    pen2 = 1
    pen1_val = 0
    pen2_val = 0
    crt_sum = 0
    crt_dif = 0
    MAX_CAP = 1000
    for pen1 in range(1, MAX_CAP):
        pen1_val = pen_calculator(pen1)
        for pen2 in range(1, MAX_CAP):
            pen2_val = pen_calculator(pen2)
            z = pen1_val + pen2_val
            if(pen_checker(z)== True and pen_checker(fabs(pen1_val-pen2_val))== True):
                print(fabs((pen1_val-pen2_val)))
main()
```

For some reason, the function `pen_calculator()` seems to return floats. I know that technically, there are no variable types in Python, but before I call the function, everything is printed as:

> 1
>
> 1
>
> 2

And afterwards:

> 1.0
>
> 1.0
>
> 2.0

(That was just me trying to find out what's wrong, it is not written in the code)

Normally, this would be  no problem, but a for-loop in the function `pen_checker` requires the "stop" to be an integer, so the code won't work. How do I solve this?

Comment: *"technically, there are no variable types in Python"* - what? If you want an integer, just use `int`.

Comment: he's right, variables don't have types. values have.

Comment: "but a for-loop in the function pen_checker requires the "stop" to be an integer" why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python integer division yields float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath ah, I see what they mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python3, if you divide numbers with `/` it will always give you a float. If you want to divide integers and get an integer, you can use the `//` operator.