# Typecasting to 'int' in Python generating wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, division

I tried performing following typecast operation in Python 3.3

> int( 10**23 / 10 )
>
> Output: 10000000000000000000000

And after increasing power by one or further

> int( 10**24 / 10 )
>
> Output: 99999999999999991611392
>
> int( 10**25 / 10 )
>
> Output: 999999999999999983222784

Why is this happening? Although a simple typecasting like

> int( 10**24 )
>
> Output: 1000000000000000000000000

is not affecting the values.

Comment: There is no type casting, only conversion. Use `//` instead to get floor division, and avoid creating a floating point number (which is where your errors come from).

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1282945/674039

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing floating-point division with the / operator. 10**24/10 happens to have an inexact integer representation.

If you need an integer result, divide with //.

```
>>> type(10**24/10)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(10**24//10)
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.x, `/` always does true(floating point) division. Using floor division `//` instead could give you the expected result.

```
>>> int(10**25 // 10)
1000000000000000000000000
```

---

The reason of this behavior is that `float` can't store big integers precisely.

Assuming [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) double precision is used, it can store integers at most 2<sup>53</sup> precisely, which is approximitely 10<sup>16</sup>. Another example:

```
>>> int(10**17 / 10 + 1)
10000000000000000
```