# Mathematical operations in Python

Tags: python

New to python and writing a simple code to convert Fahrenheit to Celcius.

Can someone tell me why these two lines of code give different results?

```
cConvert = (number - 32)/(9/5)

cConvert = (number - 32)/1.8
```

9/5 = 1.8 but how can I write the code without having to compute 9/5 myself?

Thanks

Comment: it happens because `9/5` results in an int. so you can change that return type by making either value to float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Python 2, integer division produces an integer result, so you need to convert one or both of the operands to `float` to get the desired result.  In Python 3, integer division produces a `float` result (even if the result is an exact integer), so in Python 3 the explicit conversion to float isn't needed.

Try the following:

```
cConvert = (number - 32)/(float(9)/5)
```

Or:

```
cConvert = (number - 32)/(9.0/5)
```

These should give you the result you're expecting, in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, this is an int result:

```
>>> 9/5
1
```

But this is a float result:

```
>>> 9/5.0
1.8
```

As is this:

```
>>> 9.0/5
1.8
```

So add `.0` to one of the opperands in the equations to make the operation happen as floats.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Python 2, you can fix this either by explicitly using `float` literals `9./5` or `9/5.` or `9./5.` (you can add `0` after the `.` if you like, but it's not necessary; the trailing dot makes `float` literals by itself), or you can move to Py3 semantics. Your code works exactly as written if you add:

```
from __future__ import division
```

to the top of your source file [to get Py3 division rules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html). If you want floor division, you can use `9 // 5`, but otherwise, with Py3 division, `int / int` always results in `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change either 9 or 5 into `float` like 9.0/5 or 9/5.0, or both. If not, `9/5` will return the integer part of result, 1.

Answer (score 0):

Course you are using `Python2.x`.

Related questions:
 [How can I force division to be floating point in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)
[Python integer division yields float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float)

In `Python3`

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 9/5
1.8
>>> 9//5
1
```