# Add padding to images to get them into the same shape

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, padding

l have a dataset of 100, 000 images of different sizes.

`(36,77), (56,100), (89,14), (35,67), (78,34), (90,65),(96,38).......`

l want to add padding to these images so that to get them into the same shape.
To do so l loop over the whole dataset and take the **max_width** and **max_height** then make the images into this size.
In this sample for instance `max_height= 96` and `max_width= 100`. So my images will have all the shape of (96,100). However l get different shapes :

```
(96, 100, 3)
(97, 101, 3)
(97, 100, 3)
(96, 101, 3)
(96, 100, 3)
(97, 100, 3)
(97, 101, 3)
(97, 100, 3)
(97, 100, 3)
(96, 101, 3)
(97, 101, 3)
(96, 101, 3)
(96, 100, 3)
(97, 100, 3)
(96, 101, 3)
```

What's wrong with my code

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2
import numpy as np
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def max_width_height(path):
    os.chdir(path)
    WIDTH=[]
    HEIGHT=[]

    images_name = glob.glob("*.png")
    set_img = set([x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] for x in images_name])
    for img in set_img:
        img_cv = cv2.imread(path+'/'+img+'.png')
        h=img_cv.shape[0]
        w=img_cv.shape[1]
        WIDTH.append(w)
        HEIGHT.append(h)
    max_width=max(WIDTH)
    max_height=max(HEIGHT)
    return max_height,max_width
def add_padding(max_height,max_width):

    path_char = '/cropped_images'
    output = 'dataset/'
    abby_label = []
    reference = []
    os.chdir(path_char)
    img_char= glob.glob("*.png")

    set_img_char = set([x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] for x in img_char])

    images = []
    size= []
    for img in img_char:
        img_cv = cv2.imread(path_char+'/'+img)
        h,w=img_cv.shape[0:2]

        width_diff=max_width-w
        height_diff=max_height-h

        left= width_diff/2
        right=width_diff/2
        top=height_diff/2
        bottom=height_diff/2
        if isinstance(left,float):
            left=int(left)
            right=left+1
        if isinstance(top,float):
            top=int(top)
            bottom=top+1

        white_pixels = [255, 255, 255]
        black_pixels = [0, 0, 0]


        constant = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img_cv,top,left,right,bottom, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=white_pixels)
        cv2.imwrite(output+img,constant)
        size.append(constant.shape)
        constant2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img_cv,top,left,right,bottom, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=black_pixels)
        cv2.imwrite(output+img,constant2)


        label, sep,rest = img.partition('_')
        abby_label.append(label)
        reference.append(rest)




    df = pd.DataFrame({'abby_label': abby_label, 'reference': reference})
    df.to_csv('abby_labels.csv')
    df2=pd.DataFrame({'dimension':size})
    df2.to_csv('dimension.csv')

    h,w=max_width_height(path)
    print(h,w)
    x=add_padding(h,w)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
left= width_diff/2
right=width_diff/2
top=height_diff/2
bottom=height_diff/2
```

This will lead to different final width or height depending if the width_diff or height_diff is divisible by 2. You have a workaround implemented, but that will only work for Python 3 while you are apparently using Python 2.

You can fix this in this way:

```
left=width_diff/2
right=width_diff - left
top=height_diff/2
bottom=height_diff - top
```

In this way you will make sure that

- left + right = width_diff
- top + bottom = height_diff

Note that this in particular applicable to Python 2, you might be interested to read [Python integer division yields float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float). My suggestion is to use [floor division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/2436175), so that your code is less vulnerable to the Python 2 and Python 3 differences.

```
left=width_diff//2
right=width_diff - left
top=height_diff//2
bottom=height_diff - top
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a rounding error for images with an odd/even number of pixels.

If `width_diff` is an even number, it is ok to divide by 2 as you are doing it.  But if it's odd, you need to add `width_diff//2` to one side and `(width_diff//2) + 1` to the other.  The same applies to height.

Or just run the program in debug mode (since you have the images to be analyzed) and make sure images with odd/even dimensions are being handled the way you expect it.