# Sliding a subarray along a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is something I've been struggling with for a couple of weeks. The algorithm is the following:

1. Select a subarray as an array of rows and columns from a larger array
2. Compute the median of the subarray
3. Replace cells in subarray with median value
4. Move the subarray to the right by its own length
5. Repeat to end of array
6. Move subarray down by its own height
7. Repeat

I've got steps 1 to 3 as follows:

```
import numpy as np
w1 = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
side = 3
patch = w1[0:side, 0:side]

i, j = patch.shape
for j in range(side):
    for i in range(side):
        patch[i,j] = np.median(patch)
```

Eventually, I'll be using a 901x877 array from an image but I'm just trying to get a hold of this simple task first. How can I slide the array along and then down with a loop?

Comment: While it's fairly straightforward to fix your code, there's probably something in [`scipy.ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) or [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) to do the job.

Comment: I'm trying not to use scipy or skimage, but rather write the algorithm explicitly. Eventually I'll be using a masked array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scikit-image's `view_as_blocks` and NumPy broadcasting to vectorize the operation:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

w1 = np.arange(144).reshape(12,12)
print(w1)
# [[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11]
#  [ 12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23]
#  [ 24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35]
#  [ 36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47]
#  [ 48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59]
#  [ 60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71]
#  [ 72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83]
#  [ 84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95]
#  [ 96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107]
#  [108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119]
#  [120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131]
#  [132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143]]

side = 3
w2 = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(w1, (side, side))
w2[...] = np.median(w2, axis=(-2, -1))[:, :, None, None]
print(w1)
# [[ 13  13  13  16  16  16  19  19  19  22  22  22]
#  [ 13  13  13  16  16  16  19  19  19  22  22  22]
#  [ 13  13  13  16  16  16  19  19  19  22  22  22]
#  [ 49  49  49  52  52  52  55  55  55  58  58  58]
#  [ 49  49  49  52  52  52  55  55  55  58  58  58]
#  [ 49  49  49  52  52  52  55  55  55  58  58  58]
#  [ 85  85  85  88  88  88  91  91  91  94  94  94]
#  [ 85  85  85  88  88  88  91  91  91  94  94  94]
#  [ 85  85  85  88  88  88  91  91  91  94  94  94]
#  [121 121 121 124 124 124 127 127 127 130 130 130]
#  [121 121 121 124 124 124 127 127 127 130 130 130]
#  [121 121 121 124 124 124 127 127 127 130 130 130]]
```

Note that I had to change the size of your array to `12x12` so that all of your tiles of `3x3` actually fit in there.

Comment: Your idea of using view_as_blocks led me to view_as_windows, which is pretty much exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few "code smells" I see.
Start with the `range(side)` since this number is set to `3` then you are going to have a result of `[0,1,2]`. Is that what you really want?

you set `i,j = patch.size` then immediately over write these values, in your `for` loops.

Finally, you're recalculating `median` every loop.

Ok, here's what I'd do.

1. figure out how many patches you'll need in both width and height. and multiply those by the size of the side.
2. slice your array (matrix) up into those pieces.
3. assign the patch to the median.

---

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                         
w1 = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)                                                                                                                                                                         
side = 3                                                                                                                                                                                                   
w, h = w1.shape                                                                                                                                                                                            
width_index   = np.array(range(w//side)) * side                                                                                                                                                             
height_index  = np.array(range(h//side)) * side                                                                                                                                                             

def assign_patch(patch, median, side):                                                                                                                                                                     
    """Break this loop out to prevent 4 nested 'for' loops"""                                                                                                                                              
    for j in range(side):                                                                                                                                                                                  
        for i in range(side):                                                                                                                                                                              
            patch[i,j] = median                                                                                                                                                                            
    return patch                                                                                                                                                                                           

for width in width_index:                                                                                                                                                                                  
    for height in height_index:                                                                                                                                                                            
        patch  = w1[width:width+side, height:height+side]                                                                                                                                                  
        median = np.median(patch)                                                                                                                                                                          
        assign_patch(patch, median, side)                                                                           

print w1
```

Comment: That's a great idea...this error crops up in line 5, though:

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Ok, you're np array is floats, because (I think) in python3 the division is not going to default to integer division.  So, check this out for an explanation of the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float
and I will update the code to work in python 3.

Comment: The change was made in `np.array(range(w//side)) * side` to have `//` rather than `/` because in python 3 division defaults to floating point division.  
I apologize, I know this can be confusing to folks just learning Python, but I am an old hacker, and continue to use Python 2.7

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between those two operaters @VoNWooDSon

Comment: Here's a bonus: if you find yourself used to Python 3 division, and are on a Python 2 only machine use `from __future__ import division` to get Python 3 division behavior.