# Error in Python application

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a snakes game in Python which was referred from someplace, but am getting error.

The program snakes.py is given below:

```
import random
import curses
s= curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)
snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/2
snake = [
        [snk_y, snk_x],
        [snk_y, snk_x-1],
        [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]
food = [sh/2, sw/2]
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
key = curses.KEY_RIGHT
while True:
    next_key = w.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key
    if snake[0][0] in [0,sh] or snake[0][1] in [0, sw] or snake[0] in snake[1:]:
        curses.endwin()
        quit()
    new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]
    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        new_head[0] +=1 
    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        new_head[0] -=1 
    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        new_head[1] -=1 
    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        new_head[1] +=1 
    snake.insert(0, new_head)
    if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None:
            nf = [
                random.randint(1, sh-1),
                random.randint(1, sw-1)
            ]
            food = nf if nf not in snake else None
        w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
    else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        w.addch(tail[0], tail[1], ' ')
    w.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

I am getting the following error on  `w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)`:

> TypeError: integer argument expected, got float.

I am also usng python 3.6 version, so how to fix this code.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about the error?

Comment: What part of the message are you having problems understanding? An integer was expected, but it got a float. You're passing a float (a number with a decimal point and numbers to the right of it) where it's expecting you to pass an integer. Depending on how you declared `food`, those values may be floats. `curses.ACS_PI` definitely is a float. Fix the code by not passing a float where an integer is expected. You have the type definitions and code right in front of you.

Comment: so how to make it integer

Comment: I'm not sure how you can write all of the code and logic above and not know how to convert to an int.

Comment: ok i got that how to solve it

Comment: @MarkoPolo Because he **didn't write the code**, and stole it from here: https://github.com/ebrian/engineerman/blob/master/015/snake.py

Comment: *"I have made a snakes game..."* If you're going to steal someone else's code, and then lie and say that you wrote it, you should at least be smart enough to realize it was written for Python 2.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned that am using Python 3.6. And yes am learning Python, so I was actually referred from the above link you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 the slash operator produces a `float`, even if both its arguments were `int`s.  So your line `food = [sh/2, sw/2]` produces a list of two floats.

You should use the double-slash operator which produces an `int`:

```
food = [sh//2, sw//2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
food = [sh/2, sw/2]
```

In Python 3, the division  `/` operator a[lways produces floating-point values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float).

You should consider using the integer division operator, `//`.

Comment: *(You deleted your commentwith another question, but I will leave this one.)* We are not going to debug your entire application for you. Add `print` statements, or use `pdb` and figure out where the float values are coming from. You can do this!

Comment: Your answer was first (by some seconds), so at least I tip my hat to you :-}