# Why worng answer in counting digit in numbers with python3 with right logic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I have written this code in editor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def digits(n):
    count = 0
    if n == 0:
      count = 1
    while n > 0:
      n /= 10
      count += 1
    return count

print(digits(25))   # Should print 2
print(digits(144))  # Should print 3
print(digits(1000)) # Should print 4
print(digits(0))    # Should print 1
```

But I am getting like:

```
325
326
327
1
```

Is this wrong logic or, Am i missng somthing in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`/=` performs floating-point division.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float) Use `//=` for integer division.

```
def digits(n):
    count = 0
    if n == 0:
        count = 1
    while n > 0:
        n //= 10
        count += 1
    return count
```