# In Python3, the classic mid = start + (end - start) / 2 throws TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

In Python3,

The classic binary search first step
`mid = start + (end - start) / 2` throws
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float` because division yeilds `float`
instead of `int` by default.

Is there a better way to deal with this than doing `int(mid)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python integer division yields float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, the `/` operator does floating-point division, even if it's between two integers.

You want `//` instead, which will perform integer division.

Comment: Just a small correction: `//` does "integer division". It does not "cast to an int". See for example that `type(2.4 // 1.1)` is `float`, but the value is rounded to `2.0`. However, if the operands are integers, then the result is an integer as well.