# Why does the value produced is float and not integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have declared at line 1-3 for the value to be in integer. But when running the code, it'll give me float value instead of integer unless I declare it:

`total = int(group_3 + group_2 + group_1)`
Is this because of Modulo? If so, any idea why?

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
        
group_1 = (((a % 2) + a) / 2)
group_2 = (((b % 2) + b) / 2)
group_3 = (((c % 2) + c) / 2)
        
total = (group_3 + group_2 + group_1)
print(type(total))
print(total)
```

Comment: no it is because you divide by  2 like this "/2" ... try "// 2" instead for integer division

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/python-integer-division-yields-float

Comment: You can not in Python *declare a variable to be integer.* You are clearly expecting integer division. In Python 3 you achieve that by using the integer division operator `//` instead of `/`. You may have been led to expect integer division by an outdated textbook or web page. That is how it used to work in Python 2.

Comment: @NoobCoder If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link as a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different type of division in **Python**:

1. Division
2. Floor division

I will explain with example :

```
# 1. Division
a = 5
print(a/5)
```

Result will be :

```
2.5
```

But if you use *Floor division*:

```
# 2. Floor Division
a = 5
print(a//5)
```

Result will be :

```
2
```