# How do i remove the .0 from an integer?

Tags: python

I have an integer in my code and want to connect it with other integers.

```
str1 = ''
int1 = 4
int2 = 16
int3 = 32
int4 = 64

int5 = int4 / int3
int6 = int2 / int1

str1 += str(int5)
str1 += str(int6)

print(str1)
```

now the output would be 2.04.0, but i want it to be 24. How do i remove the .0?

Comment: Use integer division `//` instead of `/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Python integer division yield a float instead of another integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/why-does-python-integer-division-yield-a-float-instead-of-another-integer)

Comment: The title is self-contradictory: If it ends in `.0`, it's _not_ an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get values as `int` so you need to change these two lines:

```
int5 = int4 // int3
int6 = int2 // int1
```

Then you can use `f-string`:

```
print(f'{int5}{int6}')
```

Or use your own code:

```
str1 += str(int5)
str1 += str(int6)
print(str1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conversion from float to int:

```
num = 123.0
print(int(num))
```

Output:

```
123
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast `int5` and `int6` to an integer.

```
str1 = ''
int1 = 4
int2 = 16
int3 = 32
int4 = 64

int5 = int(int4 / int3)
int6 = int(int2 / int1)

str1 += str(int5)
str1 += str(int6)

print(str1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix.

```
str1 = ''
int1 = 4
int2 = 16
int3 = 32
int4 = 64

int5 = int(int4 / int3)
int6 = int(int2 / int1)

str1 += str(int5)
str1 += str(int6)

print(str1)
```

If you divide than the Output will be a float (not an int). So, if you convert int5 and int6 or (like i did) convert the calculation result in the calculation to a int. The main methode you use to do it is `int()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use integer division using '//' instead of '/' otherwise you can use type casting like `int5 = int(int4/int3)`. Both of this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

As @rdas commented you can use integer division (// instead of /)
and you will get integer answer (6)

or you can just the 2 numbers together like:

```
str1 += str(int5 + int6)
```

And you will get float answer (6.0)