# When I input it is int, output it is float Python

Tags: python, integer

Consider this input code to find half of the number that you input:

```
>>> a = int(input("Please input a number: "))
Please input a number: 4
>>> if(a/2 == a/2):
...     a/=2
...     print("Half of the number than you input is:",a)
...
Half of the number than you input is: 2.0
```

When I input it, it was a `int`, but why has it changed from `int` to `float`?  *Note: If I enter numbers that requires to print out decimal points such as `5`, it will print `2.5`*.

Comment: When you divide, the result is always a `float`

Comment: Are you actually looking for mathematically half the value? or would you like to remove the decimal point?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan I would like to delete the decimal point.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other languages, Python3 does not keep the result of `int/int` as an `int`. [Python3 always returns a `float`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/).

You need to use the integer division operator (`//` or `//=`)

> [What is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division)
>
> [Why does integer division yield a float instead of another integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282945/why-does-integer-division-yield-a-float-instead-of-another-integer)

*I will keep the previous answer below*

---

If you would like to cast "integer like" decimals, use [`is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

```py
a = int(input("Please input a number: "))
a /= 2
if a.is_integer():
    a = int(a)

print(a)
```

`is_integer`

> Return True if the float instance is finite with integral value, and False otherwise:

---

Test table:

| Input | Output | `type()` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `1` | `0.5` | `<class 'float'>` |
| `2` | `1` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `-1` | `-0.5` | `<class 'float'>` |
| `-2` | `-1` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `0` | `0` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `1.0` | `0.5` | `<class 'float'>` |
| `2.0` | `1` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `-1.0` | `-0.5` | `<class 'float'>` |
| `123` | `61.5` | `<class 'float'>` |

Comment: Why don't you need the parentheses at `if`?

Comment: @scissors127 Python does not need to contain the *whole condition* in parenthesis. But you may use it in cases like `(a and b) or c` which is equivalent to `((a and b) or c)`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the integer part of the division, use the floordiv operator:

```py
a //= 2
```