# Integer division compared to floored quotient: why this surprising result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, integer-division, floor

The `//` "integer division" operator of Python surprised me, today:

```
>>> math.floor(11/1.1)
10.0
>>> 11//1.1
9.0
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#index-593) reads "(floored) quotient of x and y".  So, why is math.floor(11/1.1) equal to 10, but 11//1.1 equal to 9?

Comment: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2007-January/070707.html

Comment: The canonical question for Python 2-vs-3 division difference is [How can I force division to be floating point in Python? Division keeps rounding down to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python-division-keeps-rounding)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because 1.1 can't be represented in binary form exactly; the approximation is a littler higher than 1.1 - therefore the division result is a bit too small.

Try the following:

Under Python 2, type at the console:

```
>>> 1.1
1.1000000000000001
```

In Python 3.1, the console will display `1.1`, but internally, it's still the same number.

But:

```
>>> 11/1.1
10.0
```

As gnibbler points out, this is the result of "internal rounding" within the available precision limits of floats. And as The MYYN points out in his comment, `//` uses a different algorithm to calculate the floor division result than `math.floor()` in order to preserve `a == (a//b)*b + a%b` as well as possible.

Use the `Decimal` type if you need this precision.

Comment: But according to Python `11.0/1.1 == 10.0` is true

Comment: As we know 1.1 is stored as 1.1000000000000001, so the result 11.0/1.1 in Python is 9.999999999999999090909090909 but the closest float to this number is infact 10.0, so it happens that the result is exactly 10.0

Comment: @Tim I thought of that, and I believe this is the key to the difference between math.floor(11/1.1) and 11//1.1.  However, as gnibbler pointed out, the fact that 1.1 is represented by a slightly larger number only indicates that math.floor(11/1.1) should really be 9.0, which leaves the original question still open.

Comment: @EOL, since 11/1.1 evaluates to exactly 10.0, math.floor(11/1.1)=math.floor(10.0), however this is only due to some luck with the rounding

Comment: @gnibbler: Yeah, it's the "luck" aspect that surprised me: two "identical" operations behaving in a different way. :)  The explanation is in the implementation, as pointed out by The MYYN.