# How do you round UP a number?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, rounding

How does one round a number UP in Python?

I tried `round(number)` but it rounds the number down. Here is an example:

```
round(2.3) = 2.0
```

and not 3, as I would like.

Then I tried `int(number + .5)` but it round the number down again! Example:

```
int(2.3 + .5) = 2
```

Comment: `round(number + .5)` doesn't work if the number is integer. `round(3+.5) == 4`, when you actually want `3`.

Answer (score 1304, accepted):

The [math.ceil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) (ceiling) function returns the smallest integer higher or equal to `x`.

For Python 3:

```
import math
print(math.ceil(4.2))
```

For Python 2:

```
import math
print(int(math.ceil(4.2)))
```

Comment: Elaboration: math.ceil returns the smallest integer which is greater than or equal to the input value. This function treats the input as a float (Python does not have strongly-typed variables) and the function returns a float. If you want an int, you can construct an int from the return value, i.e., `int(math.ceil(363))`

Comment: @Sinnet: Actually one could say that python is strongly typed http://stackoverflow.com/a/11328980/5069869

Comment: @TheEspinosa: Yes, python is definitely **strongly** typed, its just that many functions ask questions about the type of some parameters and execute different code depending on the answer.

Comment: @R.W.Sinnet In Python 3, `math.ceil` returns an actual integer object, not just floating object with integer value.

Comment: Take care of float precision, due to ``10000000 * 0.00136 = 13600.000000000002`` ceil can increase a lot ``math.ceil(10000000 * 0.00136) = 13601.0``

Comment: @Ender "the function outputs a float" is not correct except in ancient, no-longer-supported versions of Python. In Python 3, `math.ceil` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 329):

I know this answer is for a question from a while back, but if you don't want to import math and you just want to round up, this works for me.

```
>>> int(21 / 5)
4
>>> int(21 / 5) + (21 % 5 > 0)
5
```

The first part becomes 4 and the second part evaluates to "True" if there is a remainder, which in addition True = 1; False = 0. So if there is no remainder, then it stays the same integer, but if there is a remainder it adds 1.

Comment: Nice. You can also use `//` for integer division, so this becomes `21 // 5 + (21 % 5 > 0)`.

Comment: ...and to have it as a nice function: def round_up(number):
    return int(number) + (number % 1 > 0)

Comment: but you would have to do a bit much of calculation for that, right? I know, you don't care, neither do I unless I really do.

Comment: Also the integrated `divmod` function can be used for this: `d, m = divmod(number) return int(d) + m > 0`

Answer (score 201):

If working with integers, one way of rounding up is to take advantage of the fact that `//` rounds down: Just do the division on the negative number, then negate the answer.  No import, floating point, or conditional needed.

```
rounded_up = -(-numerator // denominator)
```

For example:

```
>>> print(-(-101 // 5))
21
```

Comment: What about when you don't need to perform any math operation? I.e. you just have one number.

Comment: @Klik: then you can just divide by 1 ==> -( -num // 1) and you are getting your answer :-) Have a nice day! David Bau: very nice proposal!

Comment: Nice! I've always used `(num + den - 1) // den`, which is fine for `int` inputs with positive denominators, but fails if even a single non-integral `float` is involved (either numerator or denominator); this is more magical looking, but works for both `int`s and `float`s. For small numerators, it's also faster (on CPython 3.7.2), though oddly, when only the numerator is large enough that array based math is needed, your approach is slower; not clear why this is, since the division work should be similar and two unary negations should be cheaper than addition + subtraction.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't need any import and is fast makes it exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 179):

Interesting Python 2.x issue to keep in mind:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(4500/1000)
4.0
>>> math.ceil(4500/1000.0)
5.0
```

The problem is that dividing two ints in python produces another int and that's truncated before the ceiling call. You have to make one value a float (or cast) to get a correct result.

In javascript, the exact same code produces a different result:

```
console.log(Math.ceil(4500/1000));
5
```

Comment: In **Python 2.x** : int/int --> int   _and_  int/float --> float          In **Python 3.x** : int/int can result in a float

Comment: you can get the Python 3.x on behavior on certain versions of Python 2.x by enabling "true division" as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1267892/171094)

Answer (score 88):

You might also like numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.ceil(2.3)
3.0
```

I'm not saying it's better than math, but if you were already using numpy for other purposes, you can keep your code consistent.

Anyway, just a detail I came across. I use numpy a lot and was surprised it didn't get mentioned, but of course the accepted answer works perfectly fine.

Comment: Using numpy is nice too. The easiest would be with math since it is already part of python built in libraries. It makes more sense. Instead as you mentioned if you use a lot numpy for other issues, then it makes sense and consistent to use numpy.ceil :-) Good hint!

Comment: If you are using pandas and imported the whole module as pd, then just use pd.np.ceil(2.3).  No need for a separate numpy import.

Answer (score 40):

[Use `math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil) to round up:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(5.4)
6.0
```

**NOTE**: The input should be float.

If you need an integer, call `int` to convert it:

```
>>> int(math.ceil(5.4))
6
```

BTW, use `math.floor` to round *down* and `round` to round to nearest integer.

```
>>> math.floor(4.4), math.floor(4.5), math.floor(5.4), math.floor(5.5)
(4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0)
>>> round(4.4), round(4.5), round(5.4), round(5.5)
(4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0)
>>> math.ceil(4.4), math.ceil(4.5), math.ceil(5.4), math.ceil(5.5)
(5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0)
```

Comment: The input does not necessarily need to be a float if using python 3: `ceil()` [will take care of it](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.ceil) internally

Comment: Note that in python 3, `round()` will actually round half to even as described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) so the second line will return `(4, 4, 5, 6)`

Answer (score 29):

I am surprised nobody suggested

```
(numerator + denominator - 1) // denominator
```

for integer division with rounding up. Used to be the common way for C/C++/CUDA (cf. `divup`)

Comment: Relevant only for statically typed languages. If the denominator is a float you're dead.

Comment: This also only works consistently if the denominator is positive; if the denominator is negative, you need to add `1` instead of subtracting it, or flip the signs of both numerator and denominator before performing the math.

Comment: @Bharel obviously not true. Python has types and you may even check it for a value. This code will work fine for int. This is also worth noting that this code will work even for integers greater than 2^53 in which case floating point arithmetic might fail to produce correct result.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a way using `modulo` and `bool`

```
n = 2.3
int(n) + bool(n%1)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: upvoted for not needing an import

Answer (score 14):

The syntax may not be as pythonic as one might like, but it is a powerful library.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_UP
>>> Decimal(1.2).quantize(Decimal("1"), ROUND_UP)
Decimal('2')
>>> int(Decimal(2.3).quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_UP))
3
```

Answer (score 14):

For those who want to round up `a / b` and get integer:

Another variant using integer division is

```
def int_ceil(a, b):
    return (a - 1) // b + 1

>>> int_ceil(19, 5)
4
>>> int_ceil(20, 5)
4
>>> int_ceil(21, 5)
5
```

*Note: `a` and `b` must be non-negative integers*

Comment: Gives wrong answer for `int_ceil(-0.1, 1)`. Should be `0.0` when it's `-1.0`

Comment: @ogogmad it makes sense only if a and b are integers. If you have float, use math.ceil as the top answer suggests

Comment: `int_ceil(2,-1)` gives `0` for me. So the integers have to be non-negative

Comment: @ogogmad I agree, added note to the answer, thank you

Comment: @Pavel Isn't it enough that b is positive?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
a = 211.0
print(int(a) + ((int(a) - a) != 0))
```

Comment: Clever. The `((int(a) - a) != 0)` expression returns `1` whenever `a` needs to be rounded up.  You may want to expand your answer and explain how this work.

Comment: @TomAranda Can anyone explain how a boolean expression evaluates to a value please?

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone is looking to round up to a specific decimal place:

```py
import math
def round_up(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals
    return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier
```

Answer (score 7):

Be shure rounded value should be float

```
a = 8 
b = 21
print math.ceil(a / b)
>>> 0
```

but

```
print math.ceil(float(a) / b)
>>> 1.0
```

Answer (score 7):

The above answers are correct, however, importing the `math` module just for this one function usually feels like a bit of an overkill for me. Luckily, there is another way to do it:

```
g = 7/5
g = int(g) + (not g.is_integer())
```

`True` and `False` are interpreted as `1` and `0` in a statement involving numbers in python. `g.is_interger()` basically translates to `g.has_no_decimal()` or `g == int(g)`. So the last statement in English reads `round g down and add one if g has decimal`.

Comment: And if you feel fancy, you can use `int(g) + (g %  1 > 0)` instead ;-)

Comment: ```from math import ceil``` seems to fix importing the entire math module :)

Comment: @SH7890 I'm afraid that line isn't much different to `import math` in terms of what happens behind the scenes. It just drops all symbols except `ceil`.

Answer (score 6):

Without importing math // using basic envionment:

a) method / class method

```
def ceil(fl): 
  return int(fl) + (1 if fl-int(fl) else 0)

def ceil(self, fl): 
  return int(fl) + (1 if fl-int(fl) else 0)
```

b) lambda:

```
ceil = lambda fl:int(fl)+(1 if fl-int(fl) else 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

`x * -1 // 1 * -1`

Confusing but it works: For `x=7.1`, you get `8.0`. For `x = -1.1`, you get `-1.0`

No need to import a module.

Comment: Nice, but what's the logic behind it?

Comment: x * -1 // 1 * -1  =  -(-x // 1).
The // operator always rounds down, so x // 1 = floor(x).  
Therefore, the logic here to round the negated number down, then negate again, which results in rounding up the original number.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> def roundup(number):
...     return round(number+.5)
>>> roundup(2.3)
3
>>> roundup(19.00000000001)
20
```

This function requires no modules.

Comment: What if your number is `3`, then it would round up to `4` which may or may not be what someone wants

Answer (score 2):

For those who doesn't want to use import.

For a given list or any number:

```
x = [2, 2.1, 2.5, 3, 3.1, 3.5, 2.499,2.4999999999, 3.4999999,3.99999999999]
```

You must first evaluate if the number is equal to its integer, which always rounds down. If the result is True, you return the number, if is not, return the integer(number) + 1.

```
w = lambda x: x if x == int(x) else int(x)+1
[w(i) for i in z]
>>> [2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Math logic:

- If the number has decimal part: round_up - round_down == 1, always.
- If the number doens't have decimal part: round_up - round_down == 0.

So:

- round_up == x + round_down

With:

- x == 1 if number != round_down
- x == 0 if number == round_down

You are cutting the number in 2 parts, the integer and decimal. If decimal isn't 0, you add 1.

PS:I explained this in details since some comments above asked for that and I'm still noob here, so I can't comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to import anything, you can always write your own simple function as:

```
def RoundUP(num):
    if num== int(num):
        return num
    return int(num + 1)
```

Comment: This does not work if num is 2.05. You have to have at least as many digits with a 9 as your input, leaving you with a 0.999... which is 1. But then your corner case 2 is rounded up again. -- Well, I guess there is a reason why math.ceil is there.

Answer (score 0):

To do it without any import:

```
>>> round_up = lambda num: int(num + 1) if int(num) != num else int(num)
>>> round_up(2.0)
2
>>> round_up(2.1)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is from quite a while back, but I found a quite interesting answer, so here goes:

```
-round(-x-0.5)
```

This fixes the edges cases and works for both positive and negative numbers, and doesn't require any function import

Cheers

Comment: This will still rounds down `-round(-x-0.3) = x`

Comment: Also incorrectly increments exact numbers.  Eg, `-round(-3-0.5)` returns 4 rather than 3, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised I haven't seen this answer yet `round(x + 0.4999)`, so I'm going to put it down. Note that this works with any Python version. Changes made to the Python rounding scheme has made things difficult. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior).

Without importing, I use:

```
def roundUp(num):
    return round(num + 0.49)

testCases = list(x*0.1 for x in range(0, 50))

print(testCases)
for test in testCases:
    print("{:5.2f}  -> {:5.2f}".format(test, roundUp(test)))
```

**Why this works**

From the docs

> For the built-in types supporting round(), values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus n; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice

Therefore 2.5 gets rounded to 2 and 3.5 gets rounded to 4. If this was not the case then rounding up could be done by adding 0.5, but we want to avoid getting to the halfway point. So, if you add 0.4999 you will get close, but with enough margin to be rounded to what you would normally expect. Of course, this will fail if the `x + 0.4999` is equal to `[n].5000`, but that is unlikely.

Comment: Using 0.4999, it will fail to give a correct result for any input in between ???.0000 and ???.0001 (open interval), not just exactly ???.0001. For instance, if you try it with 3.00005, you will get a result of 3 instead of the expected 4.

Of course you can decrease the likelihood of this happening by adding more and more digits up to the maximum precision of floats, but what's the point to that if there are more robust and intuitive solutions at hand, like using `math.ceil()`?

Comment: @blubberdiblub In my answer I state `Without importing I use:`. I've also mentioned that it will fail if the `x + 0.4999` is equal to `[n].5000`.

Comment: Yes, you state in your answer that your solution is without importing, but I don't see the value of it. The `math` module and `math.ceil()` is in the standard library, so available everywhere for all practical purposes without installing extra stuff.

And regarding your mention of when it fails, this is incomplete in your answer, as it fails for a whole interval, not just for a single point. Technically, you could argue you are correct, as you say *if* and not *iff*, but it will make the impression on the casual reader that it is less likely than it really is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use round like this:

```
cost_per_person = round(150 / 2, 2)
```

Comment: This should work when the second argument of round() is zero. That is round(x/y,0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is pretty straightforward answer, based on use of default round()

```
def round_up(arg):
    if arg > round(arg):
        return round(arg) + 1
    else:
        return round(arg)
```

It does

```
1 to 1     -1 to -1     1.0 to 1    1.00000001 to 2    -1.00000001 to -1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use floor devision and add 1 to it.
2.3 // 2 + 1

Comment: or use `ceil()` instead of weirdly doing the opposite and then compensating

Comment: This won't work. For example: `from math import ceil; assert 4 // 2 + 1 == ceil(4 / 2)`

Answer (score -1):

when you operate 4500/1000 in python, result will be 4, because for default python asume as integer the result, logically:
4500/1000 = 4.5  -->  int(4.5) = 4
and ceil of 4 obviouslly is 4

using 4500/1000.0 the result will be 4.5 and ceil of 4.5 --> 5

Using javascript you will recieve 4.5 as result of 4500/1000, because javascript asume only the result as "numeric type" and return a result directly as float

Good Luck!!

Comment: That's only true in Python 2.x. In Python 3, division with a single `/` always results in a float, so `4500/1000` is always 4.5.

Answer (score -1):

Incase you don't want to use math, use the floor division operator //. Floor division will always take the floor or the lower number.

Problem Example:

```
x = 5.5
x //= 1
print(x)
```

Output: 5.0

Solution: Add 1

```
x //= 1 + 1
print(x)
```

Output: 6.0

You can then typecast it to int or round() it if needed.

Answer (score -2):

This should work.

```
a=16
b= int(input("Please enter a number greater than 0 \n"))

if b==0:
    print ( "Wrong input")

elif a%b != 0:
    c=a/b
    d= int(c)+1
    print (c)
    print (d)
else:
    c=a/b
    d=c        
print (c)
print (d)
```

Comment: This question is over _13 years old_ and has dozens of existing answers. Are you entirely sure that your answer brings something new? If so, great! But please explain that to us.

Answer (score -3):

I think you are confusing the working mechanisms between `int()` and `round()`.

`int()` always truncates the decimal numbers if a floating number is given; whereas `round()`, in case of `2.5` where `2` and `3` are both within equal distance from `2.5`, Python returns whichever that is more away from the 0 point.

```
round(2.5) = 3
int(2.5) = 2
```

Comment: "rounding up" means that e.g. `2.3` gets turned into `3`, which happens in neither of your examples.

Answer (score -3):

My share

I have tested  `print(-(-101 // 5)) = 21` given example above.

Now for rounding  up:

```
101 * 19% = 19.19
```

I can not use `**` so I spread the multiply to division:

```
(-(-101 //(1/0.19))) = 20
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score -4):

I'm basically a beginner at Python, but if you're just trying to round up instead of down why not do:

```
round(integer) + 1
```

Comment: This will not work for any integer i where 2.5 < integer < 3. The desired value after rounding up is 3 but your expression will turn it into 4.

Comment: I think you mean `round(integer + 0.5)` This is what I often do