# pounds to metric python program

Tags: python

```
def poundsToMetric(pounds):
    kilograms = pounds / 2.2
    grams = kilograms * 1000
    return int(kilograms), grams % 1000

pounds = float(input("How many Pounds? "))
kg, g = poundsToMetric(pounds)
print('The amount of pounds you entered is {}. '\
      'This is {} kilograms and {} grams.'.format(pounds, kg, g))
```

this program works but I am wondering how do I get the kilograms to be only even with decimal points so instead of 65 pounds being like 545.4544545454 grams I need it to be 545 grams

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you round UP a number in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Use **round()** built-in function

   ```
   def poundsToMetric(pounds):
       kilograms = pounds / 2.2
       grams = kilograms * 1000
       return int(kilograms), grams % 1000

   pounds = float(input("How many Pounds? "))
   kg, g = poundsToMetric(pounds)
   print('The amount of pounds you entered is {}. This is {} kilograms and {} grams.'.format(pounds, kg, round(g)))
   ```
2. Use **int()** casting to get the Integer part of the value:

   ```
   def poundsToMetric(pounds):
       kilograms = pounds / 2.2
       grams = kilograms * 1000
       return int(kilograms), grams % 1000

   pounds = float(input("How many Pounds? "))
   kg, g = poundsToMetric(pounds)
   print('The amount of pounds you entered is {}. This is {} kilograms and {} grams.'.format(pounds, kg, int(g)))
   ```

See output for each of these ways, respectively, below:

```
➜  python help.py
How many Pounds? 65
The amount of pounds you entered is 65.0. This is 29 kilograms and 545.0 grams.

➜  python help.py
How many Pounds? 65
The amount of pounds you entered is 65.0. This is 29 kilograms and 545 grams.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the line

```
print type(grams%1000)
```

You will get the output

```
<type 'float'>
```

So this is clearly returning a float number. Cast it to `int` to get the desired result.

Instead of doing this:

```
return int(kilograms), grams % 1000
```

Do this:

```
return int(kilograms), int(grams % 1000)
```

Now the output for your program is:

```
The amount of pounds you entered is 65. This is 29 kilograms and 545 grams.
```

Exactly what you wanted.