# Python: Rounding output from floating point input to an integer

Tags: python

Example: User needs .5 gallons of paint for a wall. User must purchase entire gallon.

This needs to be rounded up after calculations have taken place or it will affect the math

Comment: Show the Code you've tried already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number-in-python

Comment: Use the math.ceil() function. e.g. final_number = math.ceil(.25) = 1.0, you can then take the int() to remove the decimal point and trailing zero e.g. final_number = int(math.ceil(.25)) = 1.. math also has another built in function math.floor() which rounds down rather than up! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Already answered, you can use the ceil function in the math module. [How do you round UP a number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number-in-python)

Comment: You can just mark the question as a duplicate if you think it's been answered elsewhere already. Welcome to the site btw. :)

Comment: Thank you, I think I need some reputation to use flags I don't have that option yet. :)