# Round decimal number for ratings using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to round decimal number as follows:-

```
n = 3.2 result n = 3
n= 3.6 result n= 4
```

Basically if decimal is between .0 to .4 then it should round down AND if decimal is between .5 to .9 then it should round up.

```
n = 3.0 result = 3
n = 3.5 result = 3.5
```

Comment: why ? `n = 3.5 result = 3.5`

Comment: I need 3.5 should result as 3.5 only. round() will round the number up or down I want to round it in middle also.

Comment: What should .45 round to? what have you tried?

Comment: @RahulKP, because whatever I am calculating is rating average , and my rating module differs with .5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your use case, you should use

```
def r(x):
    return round(x * 2.0) / 2.0
```

Examples:

```
r(3.4) -> 3.5
r(3.24) -> 3.0
r(3.25) -> 3.5
r(3.74) -> 3.5
r(3.75) -> 4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulus `%` or substract `-` by `int`:

```
def round_(n):
    if (n % int(n) == 0.5):
        return n
    else:
        return round(n)

print (round_(3.6)) 
4       
print (round_(3.5))   
3.5
print (round_(3.4))   
3
```

---

```
def round_(n):
    if (n - int(n) == 0.5):
        return n
    else:
        return round(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

you have to make a custom round function as per your requirements.

```
def round_(n):
    if n-int(n) == 0.5:
        return n
    else:
        return round(n)
```

**Results**

```
In [21]: round_(3.6)
Out[21]: 4.0

In [22]: round_(3.5)
Out[22]: 3.5

In [23]: round_(3.2)
Out[23]: 3.0
```

Comment: Why use `str()`? How about `if n-int(n) == 0.5`?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
import math
print math.ceil(x) and math.floor(x)
```

or

```
def round(x):
    if (n % int(x) == 0.5):
        return x
    else:
        return round(n=x)

print (round_(3.8)) 
4       
print (round_(3.5))   
3.5
print (round_(3.2))   
3
```

or check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29308619/6107715