# Round up float field

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am am trying to get a float field to round up to next number in Odoo 10. I am calcuating the room width by room lenght

```
@api.onchange('roomwidth')
    def _onchange_roll_required(self):
        self.rolls_required = (self.roomwidth or 1) / (self.carpet_width or 1)
```

The carpet width is 6 so a 13x9 room works out at 2.17. I need this 2.17 to be 3 so I need to round up to next number. I have used the below for 3 digits but never rounded up

```
rolls_required = fields.Float("Rolls Required",digits=(12,3))
```

Comment: [**`math.ceil`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you round UP a number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

use the built in round() function.

ex :

a = 3.93

print(round(a, 0))  // 4.0

The round function takes 2 args, the second being which number to round up

EDIT :

oh ! Sorry about that ! 
here, try this :

```
a = 2.17
def rnd(a):
    if((a+1)-a >= 0.5):
        return int(a+1)
    else:
        return round(a, 0)
print(rnd(a)) // 3
```

Comment: but this will not work as required in question - from 2.17 it will give 2, but expected 3

Comment: he has to write custom round function which checks if there is something after decimal - it rounds base to +1

Answer (score -2):

As Drako mentioned in his comment, you need to check there is something after decimal then add 1 to base.
Try this:

```
num = 2.17
if num % 1 != 0:
    rounded_num = int(num+1)
print(rounded_num)
```