# How can I round up an entire column to the next 10?

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm really struggling to organise my data into 'bins' in Jupyter Notebook. I need the Length column to be rounded UP to the next 10 but I can only seem to round it up to the nearest whole number. I would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance. :)

```
IN[58]  df2['Length']

OUT[58] 0    541.56
        1    541.73
        2    482.22
        3    345.45
...
```

Needs to look something like this:

```
IN[58]  df2['Length']

OUT[58] 0    550
        1    550
        2    490
        3    350
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample**

```
print (df2)
   Length
0  541.56
1  541.73
2  482.22
3  500.00 <- whole number for better sample
```

You can use integer division, mutiple by `10` and convert to integers and add 10 if modulo is not `0`:

```
s = (df2['Length'] // 10 * 10).astype(int) + (df2['Length'] % 10 > 0).astype(int) * 10
print (s)
0    550
1    550
2    490
3    500
Name: Length, dtype: int32
```

Another one use [fact `//` round down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35125872):

```
s = -(-df2['Length'] // 10 * 10).astype(int)
print (s)
0    550
1    550
2    490
3    500
Name: Length, dtype: int32
```

Or is possible use division with [`np.ceil`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html):

```
s = (np.ceil(df2['Length'] / 10) * 10).astype(int)
print (s)
0    550
1    550
2    490
3    500
Name: Length, dtype: int32
```