# How to change floating point precision in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

I want to change my numpy array floating point resolution so it can only have 2 decimal places. Not to print out the value to the command window but the way the value is actually represented in memory!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you round UP a number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number-in-python)

Comment: Do you want to *calculate* with two digits only, or do you want to *print* only two digits? For example, how would you like to print `x` if `x = 1.004 + 1.004 + 1.004`? As `3.00` or as `3.01`?

Comment: I want to calculate with two decimal digits only !

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.round(your_array,2)
```

Should make it