# Subtract datetimes, round result to full hour python

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to calculate time between one date and another and give result in hours rounding up hours.

I tried just substracting, both dates are datetime `total_hours = self.valid_until - self.started_at` the result is timedelta.
I tried this one but it seems like it is viable for datetime field only

```py
         (total_hours.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=0, hour=total_hours.hour)
                +timedelta(hours=total_hours.minute//30))
```

Comment: If it is a timedelta object, you can use total_seconds and divide by 3600.

`total_hours = round((self.valid_until - self.started_at).total_seconds() / 3600)`

Comment: Not forgetting to [round up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number) the result with math.ceil or equivalent.