# Division in python. 7/9 = 0? How to stop this?

Tags: python, integer-division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I force division to be floating point in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)

I'm very sorry if this question has been asked already.

```
timothy_lewis_three_pointers_attempted = 4
timothy_lewis_three_pointers_made = 2

print 'three pointers attempted: ' + str(timothy_lewis_three_pointers_attempted)
print 'three pointers made: ' + str(timothy_lewis_three_pointers_made)
print 'three point percentage: ' + str(timothy_lewis_three_point_percentage)
```

I'm getting 0 for the percentage. How do I get it to say .5? I know that if I type the numbers as 4.0 and 2.0, I'll get the desired result, but is there another way of doing it?

Comment: BTW, you can write `print 'three pointers made:', timothy_lewis_three_pointers_made` to do the same thing -- this is how `print` is normally used

Answer (score 2):

The other option you have (although I don't recommend it) is to use

```
from __future__ import division
```

and then

```
>>> 7 / 9
0.7777777777777778
```

This is based on [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Answer (score 1):

Make one of them a `float`:

```
float(timothy_lewis_three_pointers_made) / timothy_lewis_three_pointers_attempted
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division. Make at least one of them a float value

```
percentage = float(_made) / float(_attempted)
```

You can also get nicer looking output for percentages by using the new string format method.

```
"Three point percentage: {:.2%}".format(7.0/9)
# OUT: ' Three point percentage: 77.78%'
```