# Rounding of variables

Tags: python, rounding

I have the following code:

```
x=4200/820
```

It should return `x=5.12` but it gives `x=5`. How can I change this. Thanks

EDIT:
If instead I had this code:

```
x=(z-min(z_levels))/(max(z_levels)-min(z_levels))
```

Where `z, min(z_levels) and max(z_levels)` are values that change in a for loop taken from a list.
How can I make `x` a float? Do I need to change the code like this:?

```
x=float(z-min(z_levels))/float(max(z_levels)-min(z_levels))
```

Comment: Do you actually need exactly two digits after the decimal, or are you simply abbreviating 5.12195.. etc?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python2.x `integer division` always results in truncated output, but if one of the operand is changed to `float` then the output is `float` too.

```
In [40]: 4200/820
Out[40]: 5

In [41]: 4200/820.0
Out[41]: 5.121951219512195

In [42]: 4200/float(820)
Out[42]: 5.121951219512195
```

This has been [changed in python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers), in py3x `/` results in True division(non-truncating) while `//` is used for truncated output.

```
In [43]: from __future__ import division #import py3x's division in py2x

In [44]: 4200/820
Out[44]: 5.121951219512195
```

Comment: I added some info. Thanks!

Comment: @jpcgandre just `x=float(z-min(z_levels))/(max(z_levels)-min(z_levels))` is okay.

Answer (score 4):

Use a decimal to make python use floats

```
>>> x=4200/820.
>>> x
5.121951219512195
```

If you then want to round x to 5.12, you can use the `round` function:

```
>>> round(x, 2)
5.12
```

Answer (score 2):

You should cast at least one variable/value to float, ie.
`x=float(4200)/float(820)` or use a decimal point to indicate that value is a float (`x=4200/820.`)

Or you can use `from __future__ import division`, then regular int division will return floats.

```
In [1]: from __future__ import division

In [2]: 4200/820
Out[2]: 5.121951219512195
```

To achieve python 2x style integer division (where result is a rounded integer) after this import, you should use `//` operator:

```
In [22]: 4200//820
Out[22]: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

one of them should be float:

```
In [152]: 4200/820.
Out[152]: 5.121951219512195
```