# python code to calculate xp for a project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert C++ code to python but I'm stuck

original C++ code

```
int main(void)
{
    int levels = 40;
    int xp_for_first_level = 1000;
    int xp_for_last_level = 1000000;

    double B = log((double)xp_for_last_level / xp_for_first_level) / (levels - 1);
    double A = (double)xp_for_first_level / (exp(B) - 1.0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= levels; i++)
    {
        int old_xp = round(A * exp(B * (i - 1)));
        int new_xp = round(A * exp(B * i));
        std::cout << i << " " << (new_xp - old_xp) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

python code

```
import math
from math import log
from math import exp

levels = 40
xp_for_first_level = 1000
xp_for_last_level = 1000000

B = log(xp_for_last_level / xp_for_first_level) / (levels - 1)
A = xp_for_first_level / (exp(B) - 1.0)

for i in range(1, levels):
    old_xp = round(A * exp(B * (i - 1)))
    new_xp = round(A * exp(B * i))
    print(i + " " + (new_xp - old_xp))
```

Any help is appreciated I can't seem to completely get it to work, when I fix one bug I'm creating another one.

Comment: `for i in range(1,levels)` should be `for i in range(1,levels+1):`

Comment: still getting same error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: also you need to put str(i) on  and in str((new_xp - old_xp))) on the last print

Comment: or better print(i, (new_xp - old_xp)) without the  + " " +

Comment: Please add the error into the question in future, it helps pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the last line, you can simply use:

```
print(i, new_xp - old_xp)
```

As @pfnuesel commented, you will need to adjust the range of your for loop slightly.

Finally, you don't need `import math`. You can replace the first 3 lines with:

```
from math import log, exp
```

Comment: Thank you aswell for your input!!

Answer (score 5):

Change the `print` line to:

```
print("%i %i" % (i, new_xp - old_xp))
```

Refer to this [list of allowed type conversion specifiers](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) for more informations.

Or use the new [format](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) method.

Comment: what does %i do? this fixed it by the way thanks. (got to wait 8 minutes to tag as correct answer).

Comment: It's a placeholder for an integer. You specify the actual value in the in the tuple that follows the percent sign. It works kinda like `printf` in C.

Comment: so print("%q %q" % (i, 5-2)) would print the value of i and 3?

Comment: I doubt there is a `%q` though.

Comment: Yep. The placeholders are not arbitrary letters. Each letter must match the type of the corresponding variable. I had the link with the list of allowed placeholders saved, but I can't seem to find it. Anyway, it's worth noting that the format function is the preferred way to format a string in Python 3. (The percent was supposed to be deprecated but it never happened, probably because for simple strings like these is more convenient.)

Comment: @DekDekku I think [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I was probably looking in the Python 3 section... (I actually find another one in the tutorial and added in the original answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of python you are using, the cast to double in the C++ code

```
(double)xp_for_last_level / xp_for_first_level
```

might need to be taken into account in the python code. In python 3 you will get a float, in older python you can do

```
from __future__ import division
```

then `xp_for_last_level / xp_for_first_level` will give you a float.

See the [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)