# Sum all range variables in Python?

Tags: python, range

I'm a Python beginner and I can't get one thing working.
See, our teacher told us to make a function to calculate average score of all exam scores, with undefined number of exams. It has to be in Python 2.7.

```
def main():
    print("This program computes the average of multiple exam scores.")

scoresno = input("Enter number of exam scores: ")
for scores in range(scoresno):
    scores = input("Enter exam score: ")

average = scores/(scoresno + 0.0)

print "Exam score average is:", (average)
main()
```

that obviously doesn't work, how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sum the scores directly, as you loop:

```
total = 0.0
for i in range(scoresno):
    total += input("Enter exam score: ")

average = total/scoresno
```

The alternative is to use a list and append each new value to it, *then* sum the lot:

```
scores = []
for i in range(scoresno):
    score = input("Enter exam score: ")
    scores.append(score)

total = sum(scores)
average = total/float(scoresno)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your first `for` loop you are overwriting the variable `scores` on each iteration.  Instead you should create a variable to keep track of the combined score before the loop and then on each iteration add the current score.  For example:

```
total = 0.0
for scores in range(scoresno):
     score = input("Enter exam score: ")
     total += score
```

Answer (score 0):

First, **beware of your indentation!** Python has a strict rule on code indendation.

Second, why taking a step by step average? A better practice is take all the inputs at once and then divide by the amount of inputs.

Here's your code corrected:

```
def main():
    print("This program computes the average of multiple exam scores.")
    scoresno = input("Enter number of exam scores: ")
    scoreslist = list() #Create a list of scores to be stored for evaluation
    for scores in range(scoresno):
        scoreslist.append(input("Enter exam score: ")) #Get the score and immediately store on the list
    average = float(sum(scoreslist)) / len(scoreslist)
    print "Exam score average is:", (average)

if __name__=='__main__': #Run this code only if this script is the main one
    main()
```

`sum(iterable)` sums all the elements of the array of numbers and returns the result. Wonder why the cast to `float`? If we don't cast it, we may have division of integers yielding a integer result (I guess you want results like `7.25`), so if either one of the numbers should be a float (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python) for more info).