# Solving simple equation

Tags: python, math

I have this code:

```
TP = len(set1)
FP = len(set2)
FN = len(set3)

if FP == 0:
    Score = ((2*TP)/((2*TP)+FN))
    print "Warning: FP is equal 0."

elif FN == 0:
     Score = ((2*TP)/((2*TP)+FP))
     print "Warning: FN is equal 0"

elif TP == 0:
    Score = ((2*TP)/((2*TP)+FP+FN))
    print "Warning: TP is equal 0"

else:
    Score = ((2*TP)/((2*TP)+FP+FN))

print " The Score is = ", Score
```

But for some reason my Score returns 0 every time. I checked the values and everything seems correct. Anyone could help me??

Comment: Please specify the version of Python you use. The behavior of the `/` operator is not the same between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: It should be Python2 because division operator in Python3 can return a float. `3/2=1.5` in Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using *integer division* every time. Instead of `2` constant use `2.0` to force python's division return a *float*.

Ex:

```
Score = ((2.0*TP)/((2.0*TP)+FN))
```

As a side note you can read more on forcing a floating division in this question: [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python) and in the docs: [Decimals, Floats, and Floating Point Arithmetic](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/float.html#decimals-floats-and-floating-point-arithmetic)

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thanks!