# python simple percentage calculation returning 0

Tags: python, math, integer, division, python-2.x

Okay this seems to be really trivial but I'm not able to figure this out.
I need to do a basic percentage calculation.
This is my code:

```
corr = 205
score =  100 * (corr / 225 )
print score
```

But the result is `0`.
How come? There aren't a whole of different ways to write this, but I did shuffle this around and tried adding `int()`s and `float()`s, but the results was always `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding on to @Germano's answer,

Python2.7

```
>>> corr = 205
>>> score = 100 * (corr / 225)
>>> print score
0
```

Python3 fixes the automatic casting.

```
>>> corr = 205
>>> score = 100 * (corr / 225)
>>> print(score)
91.11111111111111
```

See [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

You should convert `corr` to a `float`, that is where you get the unexpected `int`

```
corr = 205
score =  100 * (float(corr) / 225)
print score
>>>  91.11111111111111
```

Answer (score 2):

Although everyone else has a correct answer, I'd like to point out you can just add `.0` and it will be a float automatically.

```
corr = 205.0
score =  100 * (corr / 225 )
print score
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as converting **corr** to float:

```
>>> float(corr) / 255
0.9111111111111111
```

You can also refer to the denominator as a float, which will mean the result is also a float:

```
>>> corr / 225 
0
>>> corr / 225.0
0.9111111111111111
```