# Can't divide a smaller number by a larger number in Python

Tags: python-2.7

In python, i cannot divide 5 by 22. When I try this, it gives me zero-even when i use float?!!

```
>>> print float(5/22)
0.0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I force division to be floating point in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

It's a problem with order of operations. What's happening is this:
 * First python takes 5/22. Since 5 and 22 are integers, it returns an integer result, rounding down. The result is 0
 * Next you're converting to a float. So float(0) results in 0.0

What you want to do is force one (or both) operands to floats before dividing. e.g.

- `print 5.0/22` (if you know the numbers absolutely)
- `print float(x)/22` (if you need to work with a variable integer x)

Comment: Just to extend the question, what about dividing by really large numbers like float(1)/(2**100). I still get zero

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're casting the result of integer division (5/22) to float. 5/22 in integer division is 0, so you'll be getting 0 from that. You need to call `float(5)/22`.