# It keeps returning TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python, floating-point

I already read the similar problems in  here but nothing works with me .. 
what's wrong with this python code .. It keeps returning this error message:

TypeError: a float is required

```
Beta = float( math.atan([(2 - yr)/(1 - xr)]))
print Beta;
```

**Note that:**
xr = 2 , yr = 2  are predefined before on the previous lines of the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing in a **list**:

```
[(2 - yr)/(1 - xr)]
```

That's not a `float`, it is a list with one element. Remove the square brackets:

```
Beta = float( math.atan((2 - yr) / (1 - xr)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import math
>>> xr, yr = 3, 4
>>> math.atan([(2 - yr)/(1 - xr)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
>>> math.atan((2 - yr)/(1 - xr))
0.7853981633974483
```

Be careful with using `/` in Python 2; if `yr` and `xr` are integers, you'll get *floor divison*. See [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python) for ways around that.

Comment: xr = 2 , yr = 2 these are predefined before on the previous lines of the code

Comment: It might also be worth noting that  if this is python 2 then (2-2)/(1-2) = and integer rather than a float but (2.0-2.0)/(1.0-2.0) is a float.  atan copes but you can get other unexpected results.

Comment: Really thank you .. it works ! I did not notice the square brackets I was focused on fixing the float issue

Answer (score 0):

In standard mathematical notation, square brackets `[]` can be used like round brackets `()` for grouping, but they don't work like that in Python (or most other programming languages). In Python, square brackets are used to denote a list. And as Martijn said, the `math.atan()` function expects a float argument, not a list.

However, it's generally *much* better to use the `math.atan2()` function, which accepts *two* arguments, like this

`math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)`

instead of

`math.atan(delta_y / delta_x)`

The advantage of `math.atan2()` is that you can do things like `math.atan2(delta_y, 0)`, which would fail with `math.atan()`. Also, because the `Y` and `X` parts are separate, `math.atan2()` can determine the correct quadrant for the arctangent from the signs of `Y` and `X`.