# wxPython -- BoxSizers not placing things correctly

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, boxsizer

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I just made the jump from Tkinter to wxPython and I'm trying to figure out BoxSizers.  I'd look this question up, but I don't even know what to look up.  This panel is filling the space of a Frame, it's supposed to show a line of text with a progressbar underneath it and that's all supposed to take up the bottom 1/5 of the panel or so, centered horizontally (eventually I'm going to add a background image behind it).  But what happens is I only see the text and only about 40% down from the top, aligned to the left edge of the window.  Here's the code:

```
class KhPanel(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, parent, configSet, selectWindow):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    self.frame = parent
    self.configSet = configSet
    whichWindow = getattr(self, selectWindow)
    whichWindow()

def configWindow(self):
    gaugeWidth = (1/5)*self.configSet["width"]
    gaugeHeight = (1/10)*self.configSet["height"]
    gaugeMax = 100
    topBuffer = (8/10)*self.configSet["height"]
    itemSep = (1/16)*self.configSet["height"]

    vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    textSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    progressSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    configText = wx.StaticText(self, label="STUFF", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    configProgressBar = wx.Gauge(self, range=gaugeMax, size=(gaugeWidth, gaugeHeight))

    textSizer.Add(configText, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
    progressSizer.Add(configProgressBar, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 1)
    vSizer.Add(textSizer, 1, wx.TOP, topBuffer)
    vSizer.Add(progressSizer, 1, wx.TOP, itemSep)

    self.SetSizer(vSizer)
    vSizer.Fit(self)
    return
```

If you need the info, configSet.width and height are the width and height of the parent window (currently 340 x 270).  And selectWindow, in this case, is "configWindow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this code, the `gaugeWidth` and `gaugeHeight` are both getting set to zero, which is why the progressbar is not showing. This is due to the fact that you are doing integer math here, so 1 divided by 5 is 0. Same with 1/10. Just change those lines to:

```
gaugeWidth = (1/5.0)*self.configSet["width"]
gaugeHeight = (1/10.0)*self.configSet["height"]
```

Then the gauge will appear. Here's some fully runnable code, slightly modified from your unrunnable original:

```
import wx

class KhPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, configSet):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.frame = parent
        self.configSet = configSet
        self.configWindow()


    def configWindow(self):
        gaugeWidth = (1/5.0)*self.configSet["width"]
        gaugeHeight = (1/10.0)*self.configSet["height"]
        gaugeMax = 100
        topBuffer = (8/10)*self.configSet["height"]
        itemSep = (1/16)*self.configSet["height"]

        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        textSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        progressSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        configText = wx.StaticText(self, label="STUFF", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        configProgressBar = wx.Gauge(self, range=gaugeMax, size=(gaugeWidth, gaugeHeight))

        textSizer.Add(configText, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        progressSizer.Add(configProgressBar, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 1)
        vSizer.Add(textSizer, 1, wx.TOP, topBuffer)
        vSizer.Add(progressSizer, 1, wx.TOP, itemSep)

        self.SetSizer(vSizer)
        vSizer.Fit(self)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")
        config = {'width':340, 'height':270}
        panel = KhPanel(self, config)

        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You're right, that was the problem.  I did the same for the topBuffer and itemSep and now those are working, too, though I still have some tweaking as the progressbar ends up on top and I'm not sure why and the widgets aren't centered horizontally which is what I thought ALIGN_CENTER did.  Ahh well, I can fuss around with those.  Why does Python need the .0 at the end of integers like that?  Does the .0 tell it that the answer will be a floating point?  Rule #1 of debugging: test your variables -- lesson learned for the 500th time.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is telling Python to use floating point division. You can enable floating point division be default by using `from __future__ import division` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python. You might find this article useful for centering widgets - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2015/02/19/wxpython-101-how-to-center-a-widget/

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating Mike Driscoll's correction above, I changed the way I spaced it and it works out to be less work. I took out the horizontal sizers as I discovered they weren't needed unless I was going to space two things on the same row and I added stretch spacers instead of enormous borders.  Here's the new code and it looks exactly how I wanted it:

```
def configWindow(self):
    gaugeWidth = (4/5.0)*self.configSet["width"]
    gaugeHeight = (1/10.0)*self.configSet["height"]
    gaugeMax = 100

    vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    configText = wx.StaticText(self, label="STUFF")
    configProgressBar = wx.Gauge(self, range=gaugeMax, size=(gaugeWidth, gaugeHeight))

    vSizer.AddStretchSpacer(7)
    vSizer.Add(configText, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
    vSizer.Add(configProgressBar, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
    vSizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)

    self.SetSizer(vSizer)
    return
```