# Calculation of trigonometric functions in python

Tags: python, calculator, trigonometry

How does Python calculate trigonometric functions? 
I try to calculate using

```
x = ((0.1-0.001)/2)*math.sin(((1/20)*math.pi*20)+(0.5*math.pi*1))+((0.1-0.001)/2)+0.001
```

I'm getting

```
x = 0.1
```

why is that? in a usual calculator (radian) i'm getting `0.001`

Comment: Calculations are in radians, dude.

Comment: Are you running this on python 2? In python 3 I get the correct result, the problem is to with the way that the rounding is performed try adding this before your calculation `from __future__ import division`

Comment: have you tried to evaluate the subexpressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, `/` is integer division,you need to import [`__future__ .division`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python) for floating division :

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> import math
>>> x = ((0.1-0.001)/2)*math.sin(((1/20)*math.pi*20)+(0.5*math.pi*1))+((0.1-0.001)/2)+0.001
>>> x
0.001
```

Comment: "You need to import `__future__ .division`". Why?

Comment: Python 2 casts to integers by default when dividing integers. Python 3 does not, so we can import this floating point functionality.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi yeah! this is one of most basic stuffs in python! i add the link of relative question in SO for OP! that i think its better for OP that could read all the descriptions there! still i get 2 down vote!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

In [python2.x](/questions/tagged/python2.x), [python takes the floor of integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131918/calculation-of-trigonometric-functions-in-python/29131993?noredirect=1#comment46490171_29131993). Thus, you need to import `division` from the `__future__` library at the top of your program.

```
from __future__ import division
x = ((0.1-0.001)/2)*math.sin(((1/20)*math.pi*20)+(0.5*math.pi*1))+((0.1-0.001)/2)+0.001
print x
```

Comment: An alternative way is to specify floats when you want a float result.  So `1/20` becomes `1.0/20.0` (or `1./20.` or `1./20`).  (I did upvote the answer.)  You may want to change "python rounds divsion" to "python rounds *integer* division".  Actually "rounds" is also not quite right.  It takes the floor.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski which is what my answer says

Comment: actually only one operand need be a float

Answer (score 1):

Just make your integers such as `2` float `2.0`, else Python 2.x uses integer division, also known as *floor division* (rounding towards minus infinity e.g. `-9/8` gives `-2`, `9/8` gives `1`), when dividing integers by other integers (whether plain or long):

```
x = ((0.1-0.001)/2.0)*math.sin(((1/20.0)*math.pi*20)+(0.5*math.pi*1))+((0.1-0.001)/2.0)+0.001
```

and:

```
print x
0.001
```