# Recursion equation does not seem to execute properly in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following Python equation:

```
def E(r, b):
    if r == 0:
        return 0
    elif b == 0:
        return r
    else:
        return max(0, (r/(r+b))*[1+E(r-1,b)]+(b/(r+b))*[E(r,b-1)-1])

print E(1,1)
```

The recursion does not seem to work. For E(1, 1) the mathematical equation should return 1/2. However I am getting 0. And for E(2, 2), I am getting an error, when mathematically it should be 2/3.

```
from __future__ import division
def E(r, b):
    if r == 0:
        return 0
    elif b == 0:
        return r
    else:
        return max(0, (float(r)/float(r+b))*[1+E(r-1,b)]+(float(b)/float(r+b))*[E(r,b-1)-1])

print E(1,1)
```

I made the following adjustments but still ran into errors: "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python 2, When you substitute r = 1 and b = 1, the front part of the equation becomes:

```
1 / (1+1) = 0
```

So the `max` will always return `max(0, 0)`

@Alik mentions `from __future__ import division` if you need [floating point division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> def E(r, b):
...     if r == 0:
...         return 0
...     elif b == 0:
...         return r
...     else:
...         return max(0, (r/(r+b))*(1+E(r-1,b))+(b/(r+b))*(E(r,b-1)-1))
...
>>> print (E(1,1))
0.5
>>> print (E(2,2))
0.666666666667
>>>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first part be 1/2?

Comment: What version of python are you using? If it is python2, division will return an int.

Comment: Force the variables to floats to get floating point division.

Comment: I am running Python2.

Comment: @VMO take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python

Comment: I made the adjustments but am still receiving a type error: "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Comment: You cant multiply a list with a float, don't use square braces for order of operations.

Comment: @DTing I understand now. Thank you Alik and DTing for clarifying. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as best as I can tell that you are using ints where you want to use floats, also I'm guessing that you are using the square brackets as an alternative to using two parenthesis in a row. Python is interpreting the square brackets as a list and when you multiply a list by an int python will return a list with that many repetitions of the list

```
 ['a', 'b'] * 5
 ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

When you tried to multiply the list by a float python can't handle it and just returns a type error. It looks like if you just change the ints to floats and replace the square brackets with parens you should be good.

```
def E(r, b):
    r = float(r)
    b = float(b)
    if r == 0:
        return 0
    elif b == 0:
       return r
    else:
        return max(0, (r/(r+b))*(1+E(r-1,b))+(b/(r+b))*(E(r,b-1)-1))

print E(1,1)
```