# Python rounds decimal automatically

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to get a daily rate from an annual rate of 26%.

In Python, `1.26**(1/365)` gives me `1.0`

In Excel, `1.26^(1/365)` gives me `1.000633`, which is what I want.

Why is Python doing this and how can I get a more accurate result?

Comment: If you want to compare your calculations to that of your bank take into account that sometimes (i.e., not always) a financial year is assumed to have 360 days, and a month 30 days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0)

Answer (score 6):

You are using Python 2.x so `1 / 365` is zero (division of two integers returns an integer). Anything to the power of zero is 1.

You need to use true division; you could make one of the numbers a floating point number to trigger this:

```
>>> 1.26 ** (1.0 / 365)
1.000633383299703
```