# How to convert int to float in python?

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to convert `int` to `float`.

For some reason, it keeps on printing 0. I want it to print a specific decimal.

```
sum = 144
women_onboard = 314
proportion_womenclass3_survived = sum / np.size(women_onboard)
print 'Proportion of women in class3 who survived is %s' % proportion_womenclass3_survived
```

---

<sub>See also: [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869) for the underlying problem. Doing the conversion is the natural way to avoid this problem, but there are also other reasons why such conversion might be necessary.</sub>

Comment: sum = sum + 0.0 or simply sum += 0.0 it's enough to a integer number getting to a float. I'm just learning python but it seems simple (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex says: "Python fully supports mixed arithmetic: when a binary arithmetic operator has operands of different numeric types, the operand with the “narrower” type is widened to that of the other, where integer is narrower than floating point, which is narrower than complex. A comparison between numbers of different types behaves as though the exact values of those numbers were...")

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Other than John's answer, you could also make one of the variable float, and the result will yield float.

```
>>> 144 / 314.0
0.4585987261146497
```

Comment: I prefer to not do this only because it makes you have to change input that could come from a database or somewhere else (by adding `.0` to the number). Which is why I like to make the default behavior do what I want it to do :) but regardless were all on here for rep so +1 from me :)

Answer (score 54):

To convert an integer to a float in Python you can use the following:

```
float_version = float(int_version)
```

The reason you are getting `0` is that Python 2 returns an integer if the mathematical operation (here a division) is between two integers. So while the division of 144 by 314 is 0.45~~~, Python converts this to integer and returns just the `0` by eliminating all numbers after the decimal point.

Alternatively you can convert one of the numbers in any operation to a float since an operation between a float and an integer would return a float. In your case you could write `float(144)/314` or `144/float(314)`. Another, less generic code, is to say `144.0/314`. Here `144.0` is a float so it’s the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3 this is the default behavior, but if you aren't using that you can import division like so:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 144/314
0.4585987261146497
```

Alternatively you can cast one of the variables to a float when doing your division which will do the same thing

```
sum = 144
women_onboard = 314
proportion_womenclass3_survived = sum / float(np.size(women_onboard))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just multiply `1.0`

```
>>> 1.0*144/314
0.4585987261146497
```

Answer (score 4):

You can literally convert it into float using:

```
float_value = float(integer_value)
```

Likewise, you can convert an integer back to float datatype with:

```
integer_value = int(float_value)
```

Hope it helped. I advice you to read "Build-In Functions of Python" at this link:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided above are absolutely correct and worth to read but I just wanted to give a straight forward answer to the question.

The question asked is just a type conversion question and here its conversion from `int` data type to `float` data type and for that you can do it by the function :

`float()`

And for more details you can visit [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/float-in-python/) page.