# How to convert the data types between integer and float?

Tags: python

How to convert the data types between integer and float at Python?
Please help… Can you show me an example?

Comment: float(1), int(2.0)

Comment: `int()` and `float()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert int to float in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944111/how-to-convert-int-to-float-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

A floating-point can be converted to an integer using the `int()` function. To do this pass a floating-point inside the int() method.

```
f = 10.0
n = int(f)
print(n)
```

`Output: 10`

Similarly an integer can be converted to float using the `float()` method. To do this pass an integer inside the float() method.

```
n = 10
f = float(n)
print(f)
```

`Output: 10.0`

Additionally, you can use `type()` method to check the datatype of a variable.

`print(type(10.0))`

`print(type(10))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `int()` or `float()` changes the format of your data.

In case it's not a simple fix like this, can you give a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use int() to convert to integer and float() to convert to float. Eg.:

```
int(2.33) # gives 2

float(3) # this gives a floating number
```

Answer (score 0):

there is quite a simple solution for this. This is what is referred to as typecasting (at least in Java). In Python, the way to do this is by using the format datatype(value).

Here are some examples.

```
str(78)
```

This would lead to the value of 78 being converted into a string. To convert it back, here's what you would need to do:

```
int(78)
```

This is not limited to integers and strings though. You can also use it in floats, as shown in this example:

```
float(78)
```

However, please note that not all data types can be converted into one another. For example an integer cannot be converted into a Boolean value; it would result in an error.

If you have any other questions, or need some additional help with your code, feel free to comment on this post. While I may not be a coding wizard, I might be able to help here and there!

I think that's pretty much it. I hope I answered the question well. Have a good day!