# odoo 8 field divided calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make a divided field BUT why the result is always 0.00 ?

```
def _get_interest_top(self):
    for line in self:
        line.interest_top = 6/12
interest_top = fields.Float(compute='_get_interest_top',string='Interest TOP')
```

The result should be 0.5 right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=division#numbers):

> The return type of a division (/) operation depends on its operands.
> If both operands are of type int, floor division is performed and an
> int is returned.

So just change one operand to float and you get your desired result.

Comment: How to make it type float?

Comment: You probably should start with some python tutorials.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944111/how-to-convert-int-to-float-in-python