# Syntax error defining a simple function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why this simple function is not working in python 2.7?

```
>>> def a(b,h):
...     return b*h/2
... a(3,4)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    a(3,4)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: this is not going to give you the answer you expect even once you fix the syntax errors

Comment: @JoranBeasley: sure it is. The answer is 6, which is correct.

Answer (score 3):

In the interactive interpreter, you'll need to add a blank line to close off the statement before the function is defined:

```
>>> def a(b,h):
...     return b*h/2
...
>>>
```

Once you do, a new `>>>` prompt appears and you can enter the `a(3,4)` call.

From the [Python reference documentation on *Interactive input*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/toplevel_components.html#interactive-input):

> Note that a (top-level) compound statement must be followed by a blank line in interactive mode; this is needed to help the parser detect the end of the input.

Note that you may run into issues with *integer division* here; in Python 2 if both operands to the `/` division operator are integers, you'll get an integer result. See [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python) for work-arounds.

Comment: although unless there is a `from __future__ import ...` this still wont give OP expected answer

Comment: @JoranBeasley: `3 * 4 / 2` works just fine, because 12 is divisible by 2.

Comment: :P ok so it works for some cases (including the one the OP posted  :P )