# Python small decimals automatically round to 0

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

I have a simple problem:

```
print 1 / 100
```

returns

```
0
```

and

```
print float(1 / 100)
```

returns

```
0.0
```

Why does this happen? Shouldn't it return 0.01? Thank you for any help.

Comment: This may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution!

```
print 1 / float(100)
```

Your problem is that by default in Python 2 the division operator will do integer division (rounding down to integer). By making one of the operands a float, Python will divide in the expected way. You were almost there with `float(1 / 100)`, however all this accomplishes is doing the integer division of 1 by 100, which equals zero, then converting zero to a floating point number.

This is a recognized issue in Python 2, fixed in Python 3. If you get tired of writing `x / float(y)` all the time, you can do `from __future__ import division` to make the division operator behave as in Python 3.

Comment: Yay it works! Thank you!

Comment: Even simpler (maybe) `print 1/100.0`

Comment: The import command `from __future__ import division` is a very good idea. I have started using it in all my programs/scripts as default, since it was one of my top bugs.

Comment: or just upgrade to python 3 ;) (which may break something else lol)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division. What you've written is, for all intents and purposes:

```
float(int(1)/int(10))
```

For example:

```
assert float(10/3) == 3.0  # True
```

You need to have at least one of them implicitly or explicitly a float. All of these are valid:

```
float(1.0/100.0)
float(1.0/100)
float(1/100.0)
float(float(1)/float(100))
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer division, when expecting a decimal (float), you can assert an integer to be a float by placing a decimal at the end, i.e.

```
    print 1 / 100.
```