# Using fractions in equations using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write this equation with python:

```
(1/100)*((102/65520)*x - 1)*10
```

[wolfram alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F100%29*%28%28102%2F65520%29*x+-+1%29*10)

But I don't know how to apply the fractions in order to get the right result.

Does anyone know how I should write it?

Comment: If you are using Python 2 you want `from __future__ import division` - otherwise `/` performs an integer division. Another option would be using e.g. `100.0` instead of `100` to force floating point division.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'integer' division, which is default in python 2, so results are being rounded (1/100 is equal to 0, nooooo!).

You have too make the division 'floaty'. I can think of two solutions:

**1) Make the dividends become floats directly**

```
(1.0/100)*((102.0/65520)*x - 1)*10
```

You can cast integers into floats with float(), too. Then, float(102) is equivalent to 102.0

```
(float(1)/100)*(float(102)/65520)*x - 1)*10
```

**2) Use float division (default in Python 3):**

```
from future import __division__
```

Now / is float division and your code line works as it is.
Note: You should use '//' for integer division, just in case.

Credits on the second one for:
[How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)