# python -m timeit: SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeit

I'd like to compare the execution time in different ways of [forcing division to be floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python).

While testing the following code with `timeit` in terminal,

```
from __future__ import division
a = 2/3
```

I encounter the error,

```
$ python -m timeit '2*1.0/3'    # this works
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0578 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s 'from __future__ import division' '2/3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 330, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 294, in main
    t = Timer(stmt, setup, timer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 136, in __init__
    code = compile(src, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 3
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file
```

How do I measure the execution time for such a snippet code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enabling the behavior globally:

```
$ python -Q new -m timeit '2/3'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0242 usec per loop
```

Comment: In such a case, `2/3` equals `0.66` or `0`?

Comment: @sparkandshine: Did you look at the man page to see what `-Q` does?