# Timing how long something takes in seconds

Tags: java

I am trying to time how long something takes and i cant get it to spit out the seconds without rounding. Here is what ive tried:

```
long beginTime = System.nanoTime();
//Do something
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
double time = (endTime-beginTime)/1000000000;
```

I've also tried using the function `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds` and that rounds the number as well.

It should give me `1.45` seconds but it gives me `1` and it should be `1445.7191` Milliseconds but it gives me `1446`.

Comment: Try dividing by `1000000000.0` instead. You are currently performing an integer division which always yields an integer as result.

Comment: I would recommend using 1e9 rather than 10000000000.0 (spot the intentional issue?)

Comment: Or 1_000_000_000, which java will be able to understand

Comment: @MitchWeaver but that's an integer literal, so OP would have the same issue as in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force division to be floating point in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

the result of your divison is implicitly casted to int, change your divisor to a double value (add a 'd' at the end): `1000000000d`

```
long beginTime = System.nanoTime();
// Do something
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
double time = (endTime - beginTime) / 1000000000d;
System.out.println(time);
```