# How to display the decimal points in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

I am trying to write a python script that divides two numbers and then stores the value of the first digit after the decimal point but first I want to print the answer of the division.
example:
31/7 should be 4,428 but when I use

```
def spiel():
    anzahl=int(raw_input("Anzahl der Spieler"))
    spieler=int(raw_input("Jeder wievielte spielt"))
    if anzahl>0 and spieler>0:
#Quotient berechnen
        q=anzahl/spieler
        print '%.2f'%q
```

I get the answer 4.00, what have I done wrong.

If you could tell me how I can store the first decimal point after the decimal point THAT WOULD BE AMAZING!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force division to be floating point in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You're dividing an int by an int. You should use floats

```
def spiel():
    anzahl=float(raw_input("Anzahl der Spieler"))
    spieler=float(raw_input("Jeder wievielte spielt"))
    if anzahl>0 and spieler>0:
#Quotient berechnen
        q=anzahl/spieler
        print '%.2f'%q
```

In response to comment:

There are multiple ways to do that, what's best would depend on your applicaiton:

```
q =anzahl/spieler
print "{}".format(int(10*(q%1)))
print "{}".format(int((q-int(q))*10))
print "{}".format(str(a).split(".")[1][0])
```

and probably some easier ones that I didn't think of

Comment: You shouldn't have to though...

`>>> r = 3
>>> t = 4
>>> type(r)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(t)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(r/t)
<class 'float'>`

Comment: This is true for python3 but not python 2.7

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly, but how do I store the first decimal after the decimal point for example if I have 2.5 (that I calculate before) and then store the 5 or if I have 31/7 = 4.428 and I store the 4 after the point

Comment: I have edited and removed python 3 and I will try it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

In python2.7:
If you divide two integer, answer will be integer always as it will skip the decimal value.

If you want precise float output, try this:

```
>>>float(10)/3
>>>3.3333333333333335
```

Any of the value should be float.

Comment: it's automatic in 3.0 and not working for @Andreas, thats why I assumed he is using 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are doing wrong here is, you are making it believe that operands of division are integers( during division) .

I am sure you want to take two integers. You can do following things:

1. use float() during division. In here you do not need to convert both Anzahl and spieler to float. Just convert spieler :

   q = anzahl/float(spieler)

**2. Use **future** module. then you do not need to change anything in your code. Write the following line at the beginning of your code :

```
from __future__ import division
```

3. Use Python 3. In python 3 '/' means you will non-truncating division and '//' means truncating division

Answer (score 0):

If you divide an integer by an integer you will receive an integer. An integer is a whole number, no decimal points.

If you divide a float/integer by a float you will receive a float. A float is a whole number, including decimal points.

When you are doing your operations, change `spieler` to a float. That can be done with `float(spieler)`.

Your code will look like this:

```
def spiel():
    anzahl=int(raw_input("Anzahl der Spieler"))
    float(spieler)=int(raw_input("Jeder wievielte spielt"))
    if anzahl>0 and spieler>0:
#Quotient berechnen
        q=anzahl/spieler
        print '%.2f'%q
```