# Finding a sum of series in Python 2.7.x

Tags: python

Here's the equation

```
x + x^2/2 + x^3/3 +.... x^n/n
```

How will I find the sum of this series? x is a constant term to be entered by user and n which is power is also based on user!

I made this program but it's not working properly.. Have a look -

```
n=input("Enter power ")
x=input("Enter value of x")
i=0
while i<n:
    c=n-1
    res=(x**(n-c))/(n-(c))
    print res
    i=i+1
```

So how do we make it? Thanks a ton for your help!

Update : The answers helped me and now the program is working as it should! This was my first time using Stackoverflow! Thanks to everyone for this.

Comment: You need to add each value to form the sum. `res += etc.`

Comment: `c = n - 1` implies `n - c = 1`

Comment: `(n-c)` when `c = n-1` is, upon substitution, same as: `n - (n - 1)`

Comment: You're calculating the same term over and over again because c and n are never changed in the loop.

Comment: You are not using `i` in your loop. Also, you should use `for i in range(n)` instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: `sum((x**i)/i for i in range(1, n+1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this for your loop? Tried to keep it simple.

```
n = input("Enter power ")
x = float(input("Enter value of x"))

ans = 0
for i in range(1, n+1):
    ans += x**i/i

print(ans)
```

See zev's answer regarding floats

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped me :")

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding the terms together.

***Also***, you need to be careful that you use float division when `x` is an integer. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1267869/1090302).

Here's a working implementation:

```
n = input("Enter power: ")
x = input("Enter value of x: ")
result = 0
for i in range(1, n+1):
    result += (x**i) / float(i)
print result
```

Comment: @kjaquier: The question does specifically say python 2.7.x

Comment: Thankyouu! It helped me clear my conceptual thinking on this. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your program is that your are not adding the sum. See: `res=(x**(n-c))/(n-(c))`. Instead do:

```
res += (x**(n-c))/(n-(c))
```

You may also achieve it by using in-built `sum`, `map` and `lambda` functions as:

```
y = 5  # or any of your number
sum(map(lambda x: (y**x)/float(x), xrange(1, y)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! This seems really nice but I am not supposed to use the built in functions! :/ Btw Still Thanks a ton for your efforts!