# math.ceil(0.5) returning different value from math.ceil(1/2)

Tags: python-2.x, ceil

```
import math
print(math.ceil(0.5))
```

Returns

```
1.0
```

But

```
import math
print(math.ceil(1/2))
```

Returns

```
0.0
```

What's going on here? Explanation would be nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force division to be floating point in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're running that code using **python 2.x** where you need to cast to float explicitely:

```
import math
print(math.ceil(0.5))
print(math.ceil(float(1) / float(2)))
```

If you run **python 3.x** you won't need to do that cast explicitely and you'll get the same output:

```
import math
print(math.ceil(0.5))
print(math.ceil(1 / 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
print(math.ceil(1/float(2)))
```

Comment: This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what cause's Oscar's observations.