# Python Pycharm loop error

Tags: python, while-loop, pycharm

I started at university and programming in python 3.5 is one of our important courses. We use an online website to code and compile the programs but I like to save them on my computer as well but there is a slight error...

```
tolerantie = float(input("Tolerantie = "))

i = 0
fact = 1
nterm = float(1)
s = 0

while nterm > tolerantie:
    s += nterm
    i += 1
    fact *= i
    nterm = 1/fact

print s
print i
```

I use this program to approximate the number 'e' using Pycharm but my computer always gives the values s=2 and i=2 so I assume it doesn't execute the while-loop... Do I need to add something because it is in Pycharm because this program works perfectly on the server of the University?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `PyCharm` uses `python2.x` to compile the script.
You can [force division to be floating point in  `Pythno2.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python) or change pycharm configuration and choose `Python3.5` interpreter then instead of `print s` use `print(s)`.

Comment: Thnx man... I downloaded Pyhton 3.5 and changed the interpreter and now everything works fine :D