# division gives 0 in loop, why?

Tags: python-2.7, printing, iteration

the code below gives me 0% for each 20th iteration, instead of the actual percentage I would like it to show.

```
n=100
for i in range(n):
    if i% 20 ==0:
        print str(i/n*100) + '%, Progress'
```

Results:

```
0%, Progress
0%, Progress
etc.....
```

I must be missing something really simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the division to i/(float)n*100 so that the resulting output will be formatted to decimal points by the python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks all, your help is very much appreciated. As I'm a beginner this is new to me, and I definitely have to look at some of my other code, where I might have made the same mistakes by making divisions.

Answer (score 1):

Division automatically rounds down to the nearest integer. 
What happens in your code is:
i = 20
n = 100

i/n = 20/100, which becomes 0.
Then (i/n)*100 = 0*100 = 0.
You could solve this by first multiplying i by 100 and then dividing by n:
i*100/n

Answer (score 1):

`n=100
for i in range(n):
    print(i);
    if i% 20 ==0:
        print str((float(i)/float(n))*100) + '%, Progress'`

for python i/n is an (int)/(int) according to your variable declaration. so ti tries to give an int answer for i/n which is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration `i/n*100` gets rounded down to the nearest integer (this is how the division operator works on integers in python2).

You could either use explicit **casting** to `float()` or execute `from __future__ import division` beforehand. This would prevent the division operator from rounding down automatically.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python) you can find a detailed description of a similar problem.