# Why do I get different results from Python Interpreter (2.7.6) and a calculator?

Tags: python, calculation

I have the following formula:

> SZT = SZ0 + (((SZ1 - SZ0) / (WMZ1 - WMZ0)) * (WMZT - WMZ0))

Example:

```
86266 + (((168480 - 86266) / (703786 - 510531)) * (703765.0 - 510531))
```

When I use the python interpreter (2.7.6) for this calculation, I got this result:

```
86266
```

When I use a calculator (Google for example) I got this result:

```
168471.066239
```

I assume the second is the correct result.

What's wrong about the calculation in Python?

Comment: Don't post links to screenshots of numbers. Just write the numbers in your question.

Comment: Make it clear in python questions what version you're using.

Comment: Python 2 does an integer division on your `((SZ1 - SZ0) / (WMZ1 - WMZ0))` calculation instead of a float division, results in zero so it only prints the left hand side of summation. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1267869/826970) for the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically `Python 2.7` and `3.3` calculations are different to each other.

Python 3.3 return `0.1` for `1/10`, while Python 2.7 return `0`. You can enable the new division operator by using `__future__`

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> print(86266 + (((168480 - 86266) / (703786 - 510531)) * (703765.0 - 510531)))
168471.066239
```

Answer (score -1):

It has to do with the python version and the devision operator

Examples:

**Using 2.7:**

```
Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org

x = 86266 + (((168480 - 86266) / (703786 - 510531)) * (703765.0 - 510531))

print(x)


86266.0
```

**Using python 3.3:**

```
x = 86266 + (((168480 - 86266) / (703786 - 510531)) * (703765.0 - 510531))

print(x)

168471.066239
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with operators precedence but with Python 2.x doing integer divisions (ie ` 3 / 2` yields `1`, while `3.0 / 2.0` yields `1.5`).

Comment: It has to do with the devision! I have edited my post