# How to print int and float value from same input?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to complete a task like:

Read two integers and print two lines. The first line should contain integer division, a//b. The second line should contain float division, a/b.

I've tried a code like:

```
a = int(raw_input())
b = int(raw_input())
print a//b
print a/b
```

Except this, Is there any other way to solve this kind of problem? Please help..

Comment: Indentation have to be the same for all code lines

Comment: Didn't get you sir @Serenity

Comment: Your second two lines have different level of indentation. The program is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Thing is... when you copy code to SO sometimes you get the wrong indentation. Obviously that is not the problem that OP is having. (my guess)

Comment: @DYZ I've just copied code so it might show different indentation, That's not a issue, I guess.

Comment: Exactly @AntonvBR, but why my question is getting down-votes?

Comment: @BharatChaudhary Impossible to tell, but could be things like the formatting

Comment: I've Improved the question now, peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = int(raw_input())
b = int(raw_input())
print a/b
print float(a)/b
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Check your code when a=5 and b=2

Comment: It works fine, [check here](https://code.hackerearth.com/2055c8b?key=65e0409b3f1e00e2dd2dd60aa890dd4a)

Comment: Now it is correct previously it was print float(a/b).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice till you asked me. I updated now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
a = int(raw_input())
b = int(raw_input())
print a/b 
print a/float(b)
```

**note - Python 2.7**
in line 3- a, b both are int so `a/b` always give int value answer.
if one element is float type then answer in always floating value.

Comment: Yes this is a nice idea, it works. I've tried to write like      
    **print float(a/b)** but it showed me an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
a = int(raw_input())
b = int(raw_input())
print a//b
print a/float(b)
```

Comment: since `a` and `b` both are of ` int` type. So, the answer is automatically typecasted into int if we do `a/b`

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey did you get it?

Comment: Please try in Python ide divison operation `/` of two int @Arput Svt

Comment: In Python ide a/b is still giving integer when a and b both are integers.

Comment: Are you using pyhton2 or python3?

Comment: Both Python2 or Python 3

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0 Maybe it will clear your doubt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151184/discussion-between-rohit-pandey-and-arpit-svt).

Answer (score 0):

Other way? Keeping your code readable is the best of things. What you can do is format the print statement (example below):

**Update**: here is  a working example for both python2 and python 3

```
from __future__ import division # use this if python2

a = int(input()) # in python2 input() is sufficient
b = int(input())

intdiv = a//b  
floatdiv = a/b

print("{0}\n{1}".format(intdiv,floatdiv)) # this is the "normal" way to print things. \n = Linebreak
```

Or:

```
print("{}\n{}".format(intdiv,floatdiv)) # alternative
```

Or:

```
print("Int: {}\nFloat: {}".format(intdiv,floatdiv)) # alternative
```

The last prints:

```
Int: 0
Float: 0.6666666666666666
```

Docs and other examples here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: But what if my inputs are like a=4,b=3? Check.

Comment: @Bharat Good to hear. from __future__ import division is commonly used with python2 to get the python3 way of handle divisions (returns float when dividing 2 integers)

Comment: Got it @Antom, Thanks

Comment: @BharatChaudhary Consider marking mine or another as answered if you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://repl.it/languages/python) and 
Try (`Python 2.7.10`):

```
a = int(raw_input())
b = int(raw_input())
print (1.0*a/b) # float value 
print a/b # int value
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. what is a=4 and b=3. What will be floating value according to your solution?

Comment: Why @BharatChaudhary? Output wil be `1.33333333333` and
 `1`

Comment: What output do you Expect ? @BharatChaudhary