# printing variable in another function in python

Tags: python, function, global

I have function that inputs a raw score (points earned out of 30 possible) and calculates the percentage score.  I want a separate function that will print the percentage, but the following code does not work

```
def percentage():
    global x
    x = int(input('Please input the score out of 30'))
    percent = x/30*100


def printpercentage():
    print(x,'out of 30 gives a percentage of', percent, '%')
```

Comment: Don't include global and call printpercentage function from percentage function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Specifically, you didn't include what the function *does* produce.

Comment: Yes, also don't understand what you want precisely here. @alicia

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to do this is to pass the desired value into the routine.
Also, refactor this so that your functions carry out a single purpose.  Any global declaration is a danger sign (a.k.a. "code smell")

```
# Given a raw score, return the percentage score
def compute_percentage(x):
    return x/30*100

# Print the score and percentage
def print_percentage(x, percent):
    print(x,'out of 30 gives a percentage of', percent, '%')

# Main program

score = int(input('Please input the score out of 30'))
print_percentage(score, compute_percentage(score))
```

Comment: Someone has twice tried to edit my answer to "upgrade" is to handle the float computation.  Please stop, if that's your only rationale: the code handles the math just fine.  This is Python 3, so the "normal" division operator is float, not int.  If you have a stylistic difference, please offer it as a comment; I'm trying to refactor the functions while preserving some of the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, change your functions like this:

```
def percentage():
    global x
    x = int(input('Please input the score out of 30'))
    return x / 30 * 100

def printpercentage():
    percent = percentage()
    print(x,'out of 30 gives a percentage of', percent, '%')
```

Comment: When I run the printpercentage function with this code, it asks me to input the score out of 30 like the first function does but all i want it to do is print the string

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
my initial response about `print()` variable types wasn't the key to solve the issue.

The issue is, the `x` and `percent` need to be instantiated in outer scope before they get referred to with `global x`. The following code should work:

```
x=0
percent=0
def percentage():
    global x
    global percent
    x = int(input('Please input the score out of 30'))
    percent = x/30*100


def printpercentage():
    print(x,'out of 30 gives a percentage of', percent, '%')

percentage()    
printpercentage()
```

Discouragement on using `global` still stands :)

*initial response to the question was:*

In your printing function You are mixing string with integer. While print() can do both string and integer printing, it can't resolve both at a time.
So You should do:

```
print(str(i),'out of 30 gives a percentage of', str(percent), '%')
```

additionally, if percent is not neat enough your can do `round(percent)` to make it nicer.
Plus you should do `global percent` in `percentage()` to make `printpercentage()` see the variable.

Additionally, using `global` is discouraged by the community because of security and polluting namespaces reasons, so think about refactoring your code by making percentage function returning x and percentage rather than writing to global variables!

Comment: Your initial claim is incorrect.  My answer uses the original mixture of (str, int, str, float), and it resolves just fine in Python 3.4.

Comment: OK, fair enough - You're using comma as separator for print, not '+' to concatenate the variables. So yeah, variable conversion is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

(Cannot add comments, so I'll have to make an answer)
If you're using Python 2, the answer given by @Prune will result in 0 or 100, for any input between 0 and 30. To get by this, you'll have to use the following import to force division to result in a floating point number:

```
from __future__ import division
```

This will give you a percentage when using Python 2.

Source: [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0)

Answer (score 0):

The first solution according to your comment :

> When I run the printpercentage function with this code, it asks me to
>   input the score out of 30 like the first function does but all i want
>   it to do is print the string

```
percent_list=[]
def percentage():
    global x
    x = int(input('Please input the score out of 30'))
    percent_list.append(x/30*100)

percentage()


def printpercentage():
    print(x,'out of 30 gives a percentage of', "".join(map(str,percent_list)), '%')

printpercentage()
```

Second solution which is actually way to do this:

```
def percentage():
    global x
    x = int(input('Please input the score out of 30'))
    return x/30*100



def printpercentage():
    print('out of 30 gives a percentage of', percentage(), '%')

printpercentage()
```